# Defasagem do Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio

Sou iniciante em programação e consegui um material de estudo muito bom para o Visual Studio 2010. A minha dúvida é se essa versão do pacote está muito desatualizada em relação a versão 2013. Por hora, estou apenas interessado em aprender a linguagem C# para o desenvolvimento de sistemas ERP.

Comment: A lista de diferenças é extensa, portanto o recomendável é tentar adaptar as lições do VS2010 para a versão mais recente e caso algo não seja possível de fazer, ai sim, você deve criar uma questão mais específica. Se está defasado: SIM... mas não é tanto assim, que não possa ser usado como material de aprendizado.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Isso que você disse também se aplica aos comandos da linguagem C# ou eles permanecem os mesmos na versão 2013?

Comment: Na verdade, o ideal seria nem se preocupar com o Visual Studio. Não é ele que faz programas funcionarem. Ele é apenas uma ferramenta que ajuda ser produtivo. Se você tentar aprender o VS, seu conhecimento será capenga. A linguagem é o mais importante, depois o .Net. E aí a diferença é mínima. Aprender a IDE como componente mais importante é o caminho para aprender tudo errado.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Você pretende usar o material do VS 2010 e instalar e usar o VS 2013?

#### Usando o 2013

Se for isso, não é para ser tão problemático. Claro que eles são diferentes, mas essencialmente eles fazem a mesma coisa. Você vai ter que se adaptar. Algumas coisas terão aparência um pouco diferente. Mas você consegue se adaptar, certo? Se não conseguir, se a única forma de aprender for seguir a receita de bolo do seu material, então a diferença entre versões será o menor dos seus problemas.

Neste caso existe a vantagem de poder usar o [Visual Studio 2013 Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que é o antigo Professional que a Microsoft providenciou gratuitamente.

Hoje já é para se pensar no VS 2015 ou 2017.

#### Usando o 2010

Se for instalar e usar o VS 2010 para seguir o material de estudo fielmente, então não há problema. Claro que você não terá algumas ferramentas mais novas no 2013, mas e daí? Você está aprendendo, vai levar anos para aprender tudo o que precisa. Pode aprender as novidades das versões mais recentes depois.

#### O que é importante para aprender

Mas vou ressaltar que o [Visual Studio é apenas uma ferramenta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101). Ele ajuda a ter produtividade, mas ele sequer é necessário para se programar em C# e utilizar o .NET.

Se você acha que a melhor forma de estudar programação em C# é estudar como o Visual Studio funciona, você terá problemas.

O mais importante é aprender a linguagem e em seguida a biblioteca básica da linguagem contida no .NET. Entender o funcionamento de toda plataforma do .NET (não toda biblioteca) que tem especificidades importantes é mais importante que aprender qualquer ferramenta que ajude programar.

Mas antes disso, aprender a programar, entender os conceitos adotados no desenvolvimento de software como um todo, é a fundação para tudo. Não sei o quanto já tem experiência na área, mas se ainda está começando, esqueça tecnologias por enquanto.

#### C#

O compilador de C# que normalmente é usado com o Visual Studio 2010 está na versão 4. Em tese é possível usar um compilador mais novo, mas nunca tentei e não sei o quanto é difícil fazer isto. De qualquer forma o Visual Studio não teria todas as facilidades que podem ajudar as versões mais modernas. Mas nada muito importante.

Já o Visual Studio 2013 conta com o compilador do C# 5. Você pode usar outras versões mais antigas se desejar, sem nenhum prejuízo.

A diferença básica do C# 4 para o C# 5 é o uso de blocos assíncronos através das palavras chave `await` e `async`. Na maior parte da sua aprendizagem não vai precisar disso. Só quando estiver bem avançado é que terá condições de entender e criar códigos úteis com este conceito.

Também existe o recurso de atributos de informação de métodos chamadores, que é algo de utilidade muito específica e também só terá necessidade quando estiver dominando todo o resto.

Há uma mudança um pouco maior no C# 6 que vem com o Visual Studio 2015. Mas não se preocupe com isso. O que importa é que sempre vai ter uma versão nova, sempre terá algo novo para você aprender.

Outro ponto importante é que existe o [Visual Studio 2013 Community](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40609/101) que é bem completo para a maior parte das necessidades e é totalmente gratuito.

#### .NET

O normal do VS 2010 é usar o .Net 4.0, embora você possa escolher um perfil para outras versões. Isso é algo que você vai aprender com a plataforma.

Por padrão o .Net usado no VS 2013 é o 4.5.1, mas nada impede de usar o 4.0 ou outra versão. Simultaneamente.

Algumas das **principais** novidades na biblioteca na versão 4.5.1:

- Permite criar aplicação apara Windows Store usando a API WinRT.
- Tem recursos que suportam o uso dos recursos extras da linguagem (assincronicidade e *caller info attribute*).
- Possui o Managed Extensibility Framework.
- Novas versões de vários frameworks como no ASP.Net por exemplo (seria muito extenso falar em detalhes sobre cada um).
- Melhorias diversas em nas bibliotecas que lidam com redes.
- Melhorias em classes específicas como RegEx, AppDomain, Console, Zip compression, etc.

Como dá para perceber, nada muito expressivo. Ninguém sabe tudo de todo o .NET, então não importa. Decorar biblioteca é contraprodutivo, então é até melhor ir deixando os detalhes para depois.

De qualquer forma nenhum material de estudo, por melhor que seja, vai ensinar tudo o que tem para aprender.

#### Diferenças do Visual Studio

O VS 2010 (versão 10.0) e o VS 2013 (versão 12.0) possui de cara uma interface gráfica bem diferente, baseada mais no visual do Windows 8. Mesmo quando não está rodando nele. Há inclusive muita polêmica se ficou melhor ou pior.

A quantidade de ferramentas novas e melhoradas, principalmente se considerar os recursos de ciclo de vida de produto e não só no desenvolvimento mais direto do software, são tão grandes que a resposta precisaria de um capítulo de um livro.

Mas isso não é importante. Como eu disse antes, ele é apenas uma ferramenta, que ajuda muito, mas é a parte menos importante do que você tem que aprender. E novamente digo que tem tanta coisa para aprender nele, vai levar tanto tempo para aprender tudo, que não faz diferença qual versão está usando. Só não vá usar uma versão muito antiga.

Todas essas ferramentas novas e melhoradas são ótimas se você souber muito bem como programar em C#, ter o domínio do .NET e outras tecnologias relacionadas. Sem isso, as ferramentas (ou mesmo as antigas, mas principalmente as novas) não servem para nada.

Eu particularmente usaria a versão mais nova mesmo tendo um material mais velho, embora eu também procuraria um material mais novo. Mas note que eu sei me virar bem com qualquer coisa que eu tenha em mãos. Nem todo mundo consegue fazer a adaptação necessária quando encontra um ícone ou um nome diferente do que está no material de estudo, quando a posição ou cor de elementos é diferente. Claro que este tipo de adaptação será necessário para qualquer desenvolvedor profissional.

Nem vou recomendar nada porque este não é o objetivo do SOpt. Eu lhe dei subsídios para decidir por conta própria.

#### Finalmente

Não importa o que você vai fazer com o C#, ERP, aplicação científica, jogo, etc. O caminho inicial é o mesmo.

Não sei qual o material de estudo que você tem, mas um livro muito bem estruturado, conceituado, que realmente seja didático é o caminho. Se o material que você tem é apostila, tutorial, vídeos, coisas soltas, provavelmente vai começar errado.

Comment: Bigown, obrigado pela dedicação ao me responder.

Depois dessas explanações, acho que seguirei sua sugestão de fazer uso do VS2013. Somente se o estudo complicar com essa versão eu recorro ao VS2010 – o que eu torço que não aconteça.

O material de estudo que eu tenho são as videoaulas de C# básico (WA1) e C# avançado (WA2) do site Treinamentos TI – o qual eu espero que me capacite atuar na área de desenvolvimento ou, pelo menos, me deixe bem próximo dessa meta.

Comment: Esses videos curtos normalmente não ensinam ninguém programar. Então não faz diferença se você está usando uma versão nova ou uma antiga. É só uma introdução do básico do básico. Se você achar que dezenas de horas de vídeos vão te ensinar mais que 1% (que já é muito) do que precisa para desenvolver sistemas, vai ficar com uma formação extremamente deficiente.

Comment: Bom, eu só opinarei sobre isso que você disse depois que tiver terminado o estudo. Outros programadores elogiaram essas videoaulas. De qualquer forma, qual a sua dica para uma formação não deficiente?

Comment: Livros completos. Você consegue ler razoavelmente em inglês? è o ideal. Tem algumas traduções de livros bons mas que em português eles ficam bem piores. Longe de dizer que é uma formação completa, mas livros com entre 1000 e 2000 páginas já ajudam bem. Eu não os segui porque não sou iniciante há muito tempo, mas o pessoal costuma indicar o C# How to Program do Deitel e o Head First (bem focado na didática) que no Brasil se chama Use a Cabeça. Depois disso precisará ir atrás de livros mais avançados, e sobre outros assuntos. Tem que ler todos os clássicos da computação.

Comment: Eu já passei em dois exames Microsoft em inglês, então, acho que posso dizer que consigo ler razoavelmente textos nessa língua. 

Eu imaginava que você fosse dizer livros. Esses dois que você indicou, eu me deparei com eles nas minhas pesquisas. Depois que terminar com as videoaulas, definitivamente, vou partir para eles. Obrigado pelas dicas.