# Visual Studio Community pode ser usado em projetos comerciais?

Tags: visual-studio, licença

Li essa semana que agora existe uma edição do VS chamada Visual Studio Community. Já tem a versão 2013 pra baixar e vai ter a 2015 também assim que sair. Pelo que estava lendo, a partir do VS 2015 não vai existir mais o Express e só vai ter essa versão Community.

O que não entendi muito bem foi a limitação imposta nessa versão Community. Ela é muito mais completa do que as versões express antigas. Li [nesse artigo](http://techcrunch.com/2014/11/12/microsoft-makes-visual-studio-free-for-small-teams/) que a nova versão Community pode ser usada em quaisquer projetos (comerciais e não comerciais) desde que não seja por uma empresa e seja uma equipe de no máximo 5 programadores.

Já no site da Microsoft diz isso:

> Download Visual Studio Community for a free, full-featured IDE with powerful coding productivity features, cross-platform mobile development tools for Windows, iOS and Android, and access to thousands of extensions. This edition of Visual Studio is available at no cost for non-enterprise application development.

Mas fiquei em dúvida se esse "non-enterprise application development" significa "desenvolvimento fora de empresas" como diz no artigo ou se significa "desenvolvimento de aplicações que não sejam para empresas".

Dessa forma, minha pergunta é a seguinte: um programador que trabalha sozinho, ou com uma equipe de no máximo 5 programadores, desde que trabalhe por conta própria fora de uma empresa poderá usar o VS Community em qualquer projeto seja ele comercial ou não comercial e seja ele código aberto ou fechado?

Comment: Todas as versões:
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/pt-br/license-terms/ Versão community 2019
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/pt-br/license-terms/mlt031819/

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Sim, pode desde que você **não** esteja **desenvolvendo** dentro de uma empresa nas seguintes condições:

- tenha mais de 5 desenvolvedores usando esta versão (muito raro projetos terem mais de 5) ou
- esteja em uma grande corporação (250 computadores ou faturamento anual acima de 1 milhão de dólares, o que não é tão grande assim (uma terceirização pode resolver).

A limitação é apenas esta. Se cumprir isto pode usá-lo para fazer o que quiser. E lembre-se que estamos falando do Visual Studio.

O .NET ficou totalmente livre, [licença MIT](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT), portanto mais aberto que grande parte das outras plataformas existentes no mercado.

*Non-enterprise* neste caso significa fora de grandes empresas. Nos EUA o termo costuma ser usado apenas para grandes empresas. [Aqui há uma definição melhor do que é *enterprise*](https://web.archive.org/web/20190121212553/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/b/dorischen/archive/2014/11/12/q-amp-a-on-visual-studio-community-2013-and-2015-preview.aspx). Procure por `How do you define “non-enterprise app”`.

Ainda é possível usá-lo se a sua empresa não cumpre estas condições. Mas aí só poderá ser usado para fins educacionais (ensino e pesquisa) ou projetos *open source*. Há restrição no tipo de projeto se a empresa não cumpre as limitações de tamanho citadas. Mas pense em empresa que está desenvolvendo e não empresa que vai usar a aplicação final.

Uso individual está obviamente totalmente liberado. Mesmo que o seu desenvolvimento sirva grandes empresas indiretamente.

Fonte: [Microsoft](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

De fato não está claro [todos os detalhes](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13350&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) mas ali deixa base clara que o que importa é o ambiente de desenvolvimento. Nem tem como limitar o uso do software criado no VS. Seria impossível impedir mesmo que apenas legalmente (nem falo tecnicamente porque isto é óbvio que não dá para impedir).

O fato é que esta nova licença se refere apenas ao Visual Studio e ele só é usado em tempo de desenvolvimento. Depois que sua aplicação saiu dali não importa onde ela foi construída, se foi no Express, Community, Ultimate, no pirata, SharpDevelop, Notepad ou qualquer outra forma. Não importa quem vai usar a aplicação final, se será vendida ou dada, se é aberta ou proprietária.

O que não está claro, pelo menos deixa aberto, se você trabalha para uma empresa de desenvolvimento ou grande empresa que desenvolve seus próprios softwares que tem mais de 5 desenvolvedores mas eles não são funcionários dela, essas pessoas contam em conjunto? Se eles trabalham essencialmente remotamente, conta? Se trabalham lá em uma parte do tempo mas com seu próprio *notebook*, esse desenvolvedor conta? Sei lá, na prática parece difícil fiscalizar, eu duvido que vá acontecer alguma coisa se você conseguir minimamente explicar porque tem mais que 5 desenvolvedores usando o [VS Community](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40609/101) no local de forma não permanente por arranjos que não foram a empresa que providenciou. Mas nesse ponto é só minha opinião. Acho que vai ficar mais na consciência de cada um em casos limites.

Ele inclui até o Xamarin que pode ser usado sem restrições. Claro que o [Visual Studio Enterprise](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/152242/101) fornece ferramentas mais avançadas, e esta sempre é paga.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Grandes empresas com restrições orçamentárias usam a versão Express, simplesmente por dev não ser o core do negócio. A estratégia da Microsoft faz sentido, porém pessoalmente eu ficaria triste se o Express deixa-se de existir - o que é muito provável =(

Comment: @gmsantos O Express ficará desatualizado em recursos, mas ainda poderá ser usado por um longo tempo. "As versões existentes do Visual Studio Express (ex: 2010, 2013) permanecerão, mas no momento nós não estamos planejando liberar uma versão Express para 2015. A edição Community se tornará a primeira e melhor oferta gratuita para desenvolvedores criarem aplicativos não enterprise." http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dorischen/archive/2014/11/12/q-amp-a-on-visual-studio-community-2013-and-2015-preview.aspx

Answer (score 12):

## P: Quem pode usar o Visual Studio Community?

## R:

- Veja como os desenvolvedores **individuais** podem usar o Visual Studio Community:

  - Qualquer desenvolvedor individual pode usar o Visual Studio Community para criar seus próprios aplicativos gratuitos ou pagos.
- Veja como Visual Studio Community pode ser usado nas **organizações**:

  - Um número *ilimitado* de usuários dentro de uma organização pode utilizar o Visual Studio Community para os seguintes cenários: em um ambiente de *aprendizagem da sala de aula*, para a *pesquisa acadêmica*, ou para contribuir para projetos de *código aberto*.
  - Para todos os outros cenários de uso: 
    Em organizações **não-empresariais**, até 5 usuários podem usar o Visual Studio Community. 
    Nas organizações **empresariais** (ou seja, aqueles com> 250 PCs ou> $ 1 MM de receita anual), não é permitido o uso além do código aberto, a pesquisa acadêmica e os cenários do ambiente de aprendizagem da sala de aula descrito acima.

http://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs
Google Tradutor