# Ícone da aplicação no Visual Studio 2012 Express

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Como faço para definir o ícone da aplicação no Visual Studio 2012 Express?

```
ps: Da executável.

ps²: Aplicação C++
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como você vem perguntando sobre C++ vou entender que é este tipo de aplicação que está falando.

O que vou mostrar a seguir [não está disponível nas versões Express](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/d4cfawwc(v=vs.110)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) (a pergunta original não falava nisto). Mas não importa, baixe a versão [Community 2013](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/40610/101) (2015 estará disponível em breve) que é essencialmente a Professional. É totalmente gratuito.

## Arquivo de recursos

Basicamente você precisa inserir um ícone ([`.ico`](http://www.convertico.com/)) como *resource* no arquivo. Mais ou menos assim:

1. Vá no menu `VIEW > RESOURCE VIEW`
2. Com o botão direito no `Resource view` vai entrar em `ADD > RESOURCE...`
3. Escolher o `.ico` e clicar em `IMPORT` (selecione apenas `*.ico`, não pode usar outros arquivos)

## Manual

Se precisar conferir procure o arquivo `resource.h` para ver os ícones constantes lá. Se você colocar vários ícones, o ícone da aplicação será o que tem o meno identificador.

Também é possível incluir um ícone (`meuicone.ico` por exemplo) manualmente no arquivo de recurso, por exemplo o `resource.rc`:

```
101  ICON  "meuicone.ico"
```

Ou

```
MAINICON ICON "meuicone.ico"
```

## Gambiarra no Express

Existe um truque para fazer isto no Express conforme essa [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20436114/221800).

Outra solução [nesse blog](http://www.bradmurgen.com/2011/11/changing-icons-in-visual-c-express.html).

Comment: Eu omiti alguns dados. Eu uso a versão express, é possivel definir o icone da aplicação? ps: Não há a opção "Resource View" no menu "View".

Comment: Sabia que não há mais necessidade de usar versões Express? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/40610/101. Eu acho que é para ter esta opção mesmo na versão Express. Tem a opção de fazer na mão.

Comment: Interessante, não sabia. Pode mostrar na sua resposta como faz "na mão"? Em breve usarei outra versão, mas por enquanto, vou continuar o aprendizado com essa.

Comment: Atualizei com o que acabei de descobrir.

Comment: Nenhum dos dois métodos funcionou no VC++ 2012.

Comment: Se não estiver fazendo nada errado, o que pode ser que não esteja mesmo, a resposta seria: não dá, troque para o 2013 Community.

Comment: Então irei baixar.