# Ribbon para Visual Studio Express 2013

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio, wpf

Como instalar ou ativar Ribbon no Visual Studio Express 2013?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro quero dizer que você provavelmente não precisa mais usar este Visual Studio limitado. Há uma versão quase completa gratuita chamada [Visual Studio Community Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Mais detalhes podem ser obtidos [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40609/101).

Ele é importante se deseja instalar extensões nele. O Express limita bastante o que pode instalar.

Se você está usando WPF já tem um [Ribbon nativo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ff799534(v=vs.110)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) e é recomendado o seu uso. Você já deve ser capaz de usá-lo diretamente sem ações adicionais.

Se está usando Windows Forms é possível usar um [projeto Open Source disponível no CodePlex](https://github.com/RibbonWinForms/RibbonWinForms). [Instruções de instalação](https://github.com/RibbonWinForms/RibbonWinForms/wiki). Se tiver algum problema específico para instalar, estamos à disposição para uma pergunta específica.

Existem outras [opções gratuitas](https://github.com/RibbonWinForms/RibbonWinForms/wiki/Alternative-Ribbon) e pagas, incluindo dos principais fornecedores de controles para .NET.

Também é possível usar o Windows SDK que possui um controle de [Ribbon para C++/MFC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/ribbon-designer-mfc?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=vs-2019) e acessá-lo. Não é tarefa tão simples para que não conhece bem como fazer interoperabilidade com código não gerenciado mas é uma alternativa.