# É recomendável utilizar C# 6 no Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, ide, .net-compiler-platform

No `Visual Studio 2015` vejo que é possível definir a versão do C#:

[image: Fonte: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/865579/How-to-change-targeted-Csharp-version-in-Visual-St]
Fonte: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/865579/How-to-change-targeted-Csharp-version-in-Visual-St

Porém no `Visual Studio 2013` é necessário a instalação de um pacote `Microsoft.Net.Compilers 1.0.0` via nuget com uma "ajuda" do `Resharper` é possível habilitar o suporte a versão 6 do `C#`:

[image: Habilitando C# 6 no VS2013]

De acordo com esta [resposta (Will C# 6.0 ever be supported by `VS 2013`?)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/49ba9a67-d26a-4b21-80ef-caeb081b878e/will-c-60-ever-be-supported-by-vs-2013?forum=roslyn) na `MSDN`, o `VS2013` não suportaria a versão 6 do C#.

Seria recomendável realizar este procedimento e utilizar `C# 6.0` em projetos no `VS2013`?

Comment: A pergunta a rigor não faz muito sentido: "Seria recomendável realizar este procedimento e utilizar C# 6.0 em produção no VS2013?". Se você está no VS2013, não está em produção, obviamente.

Comment: Realmente estava confuso o termo `produção`, quis me referir a projetos `reais, grandes, etc`. @CiganoMorrisonMendez

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O recomendável é usar o Visual Studio 2015 (ou mais novo), não tem outra solução. E ao que tudo indica não terá, existem umas gambiarras mas ficará ruim.

Não tem como usar o Visual Studio 2013 em sua plenitude com o C# 6. Claro que dá para usar o compilador novo com ele, como você já constatou. Dá para fazer isto sem IDE algum. Mas não há suporte no IDE, não há ajuda ou benefício algum. Mesmo com o Resharper ficará bem aquém.

Se puder usar o [Visual Studio Community](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40609/101), basta baixar e instalar. Ele é bem completo, faz 99% das coisas que 99% dos usuários precisam e ainda pode ser estendido. O 2015 já está disponível (na data da resposta, vieram várias versões depois, na edição da resposta já tinha o 2022).