# Portar código Visual C++ para outra linguagem

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, codeblocks

Seguinte , tenho um código de um simples ShellExecute que foi feito no Visual C++ 2012, mas por ser uma plataforma fechada e paga e por precisar que meus clientes precisem ficar baixando programas a mais eu gostaria que esse projeto fosse portado para outra linguagem .
Irei postar o código principal e o link do projeto no GitHub.

https://github.com/zoiobnu/L2-EXE

Preciso desse código, sem precisar do Visual Studio , sem precisar de DLL's a mais no computador do cliente , preciso apenas que ele pegue o executável e execute dentro do jogo.

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT _WIN32_WINNT_WINXP
#define NOMINMAX
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>

// Start L2 as .bin with IP as parameter.
// You can use IP or DNS as IP parameter.
// You could include other parameters.
// You can change the path to the .bin file to avoid including the L2.exe inside the System folder.
// Author: Zoey76
int _stdcall wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE prevInst, LPWSTR szCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    ShellExecute(0, L"open", L"cmd.exe", L"/C start l2ellite/l2.bin IP=127.0.0.1", 0, SW_HIDE);
}
```

Comment: Aproveitando que você parece ser novo aqui, veja alguns links que podem ajudar na elaboração das perguntas: [Tour], [Ask] e também o [FAQ da Comunidade](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/699). Aliás, para usuário novo, sua pergunta já está bem formatada, talvez se melhorar um pouco o conteúdo com mais detalhes da necessidade (tipo de ambiente que vai usar, compilador desejado etc) pode ser que se torne uma boa pergunta, pois o tema é interessante. Os links recomendados podem ajudar nesse sentido. E é claro, seja bem-vindo.

Comment: Não entendi o que é que você está perguntando.

Comment: Só uma nota: CodeBlocks é uma IDE e não um compilador, no caso ele usa o Mingw por padrão (acho que dá pra usar outros compiladores).

Comment: E precisa mesmo de um executável só para isso? Se criar um arquivo `.bat`com o comando `start l2ellite/l2.bin IP=127.0.0.1` deve funcionar da mesma forma.

Comment: Se eu criar um .bat funciona , mas por questão de segurança, não quero que meus players vejam o IP do servidor .

Comment: Criar um executável só dá sensação de segurança. Alias, nem precisa proteger alguma coisa, dá para saber mesmo que fosse possível proteger

Comment: Muito dos jogadores nem sabem como olhar , mas enfim se não querem ajudar podem fechar o post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A pergunta não está muito clara e talvez seja um pouco ampla, mas o que está querendo fazer não faz muito sentido.

Você pode se livrar do Visual Studio mas não pode se livrar do Windows que é uma plataforma fechada e paga.

Mas não sei se isto tem relevância. Qual o problema do Visual Studio ser fechado? Causa algum problema real? Que eu saiba, não. E [ele não é pago para imensa maioria dos casos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40609/101), mesmo a versão quase completa é muito melhor que a maioria dos softwares semelhantes que existem por aí.

Alguma coisa terá que ser baixada. Mesmo que não seja um produto da Microsoft. O menor dos problemas que a pessoa terá é baixar o Visual Studio.

O trecho mostrado não mostra nada que seja específico do compilador da Microsoft, então não tem o que ser portado. Existe acesso à API do Windows. Mas isto não pode ser portado sem jogar fora o que está fazendo. Na verdade este código tem pouco sentido também. Não sei se vai existir algo mais, mas obrigar alguém baixar um compilador para compilar só isto é um enorme exagero. Não precisa fazer um "software em C++" só para chamar o programa. Ninguém faz isto, se quer fazer diferente, só você sabe quais diferenças quer.

Pode ser que não seja a resposta que espera, mas a solução real é esta. A não ser que que a pergunta não esteja nada clara.

Comment: No caso esse é um launcher de um jogo, ele invoca o jogo sem a necessidade de eu alterar o jogo em si. No caso o rapaz deu essa resposta.
Me desculpe a sinceridade mas nunca vi por exemplo um Mozilla Firefox , ou Teamspeak precisar baixar programas adicionais. Sei que falei no code::blocks mas dei como uma referencia , pra mim não importa a linguagem que será usada , só preciso que esse executável invoque o L2.bin com o endereço IP que necessito, mas como eu disse não quero que meu cliente baixe nada da microsoft.

Comment: É, eu também nunca ouvi falar nisso, por isso você está fazendo algo muito errado, mas muito mesmo. Pra falar a verdade acho que é até melhor fechar a pergunta, porque ela parece não ter sentido algum. O problema é outro e sequer precisa de programação de fato. Você está contratando um avião para levar um palitinho ali na esquina.

Comment: Até entendo seu ponto , mas o problema é que preciso desse launcher , ou pelo menos portado para o Visual Studio 2008 pois geralmente o pessoal tem. Por exemplo instalei no outro computador o jogo e esse launcher , baixei o Visual C++ , instalei , reiniciei o computador e ainda assim ele não acha a DLL do Visual C++

Comment: Deixa eu esclarecer, não entendo nada quase de programação .
Este código está no GitHub só dei fork nele , mas não quero usar o Visual Studio 

a: Pois é pago
b: Pois é pesado 
c: Pois o cliente precisa do Visual C++ para usar
d: Pois é Microsoft

Talvez agora eu tenha sido mais claro sobre o que preciso e porque não consigo usar em outro software. Tentei importar ele para o code: blocks e compilar com o minGW mas ele não compila.