# Quais as diferenças entre as versões disponíveis do Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, gerenciamento-de-projetos

No ano passado foi anunciado 3 versões do **Visual Studio 2015**: *Community, Professional e Enterprise*

Com base nas ferramentas disponíveis em cada versão:

- o que eu perco entre usar uma e outra em parte de produtividade e ferramentas disponíveis?
- (opcional) é recomendado para que tipos de projetos, se possível exemplos?! (ex: pequenos projetos como um aplicativo de um site, perda de ferramentas de emulação de celulares,...)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Professional

O [Visual Studio Community](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40609/101) em si não tem nada a menos que o Professional. Pode haver alguns benefícios além do IDE que a Microsoft só dá na versão paga. Entre eles destacam-se o [Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/what-is-visual-studio-online-vs.aspx?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) na sua plenitude e o Team Foundation Server (isso andou mudando o erviço é até outro agora). Também disponibilidade de diversos softwares (SQL Server, Exchange, etc.) para uso em ambiente de desenvolvimento, além de créditos em diversos serviços. No *link* acima pode ser visto as restrições de uso desta versão.

## Enterprise

A edição Enterprise tem vários recursos extras principalmente ligados ao [ALM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_lifecycle_management), testes e *debugging* (alguns já não são mais exclusivos desta edição). Há uma [tabela comparativa oficial](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-2015-products-vs?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Destaco:

- IntelliTrace (*debug* histórico)
- .NET Memory Dump Analysis
- Code Map Debugger Integration
- Web Load & Performance Testing
- IntelliTest
- Microsoft Fakes (Unit Test Isolation)
- Code Coverage
- Coded UI Testing
- Manual Testing
- Exploratory Testing
- Test Case Management
- Fast-forward for Manual Testing
- CodeLens
- CodeClone
- Architectural Layer Diagrams
- Architecture Validation
- UML Diagrams
- Virtual environment setup & teardown
- Provision environment from template
- Checkpoint environment
- Web-based Test Case Management
- Release Management
- Test Manager
- Recursos extras para o Xamarin (Android e iOS), incluindo Remote Simulator
- Testes de unidade em "tempo real"
- Ferramentas extras de SQL de terceiros

[Isso pode interessar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21672/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 0):

Vai de acordo com o que você quer utilizar mesmo a grosso modo.

O Community principalmente é com o foco acadêmico (ferramentas básicas para desenvolvimento), porém, não é tão flexível quanto o Professional a cerca de ferramentas. Já o Enterprise existe teste de unidade como ferramenta por exemplo (mas pode se utilizar outros programas que façam TestUnit). São em si ferramentas mesmo que diferenciam umas das outras. Eu utilizo o Visual Studio Professional no trabalho mas em casa tenho o Community e particularmente o Professional pode te dar muito mais benefício comparado ao Community.

Mais dúvidas segue o [Link](https://www.visualstudio.com/pt-br/products/vs-2015-product-editions.aspx) do site da MS falando sobre os produtos perguntados.

Comment: O Community não tem foco acadêmico, o foco é amplo e é comercial. O IDE em si é igual ao Professional.

Comment: @bigown interessante o que você disse, mas eu achei o Community digamos ''pelado'' comparado ao Professional. Por isso eu senti uma pegada meio pra fins acadêmicos.

Comment: Achar é uma coisa, ser é outra bem diferente. As respostas não podem ser o que a pessoa acha e sim o que é.

Comment: @bigown o termo achar, seria pela proposta da Microsoft entre utilizar do Community uma ideia de compartilhar conhecimentos e etc. Por isso eu considero de uma forma uma pegada acadêmica TAMBÉM. Assim como é proposta citada no próprio site de microsoft para contribuição com projetos de código aberto.