# Licença de software no Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, licença

Comercializar um software feito em C# utilizando WF ou WPF de forma autônoma requer algum tipo de licença especifica (Devo pagar por alguma versão do VS para desenvolver) ou posso simplesmente desenvolver e comercializar?

Comment: Relacionada: [Visual Studio Community pode ser usado em projetos comerciais?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40609/91)

Comment: Veja também: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/121997/101. Note que está se falando apenas do Visual Studio. O. Net e o C# podem ser usados sempre em qualquer situação sem limitação. Sempre pode, e hoje pode até mesmo mexer nele mesmo à vontade. Se confunde linguagem, compilador e IDE, veja http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/121997/101. Veja também: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38099/101.