# Plug-in utilizar TypeScript no NetBeans 8.1?

Tags: typescript, netbeans, ide

Estou utilizando o NetBeans 8.1, porém ele não reconhece a sintaxe do [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/).

Existe algum *plug-in* que funcione bem com [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) no NetBeans 8.1? Caso não exista, qual IDE seria indicado?

Comment: Apesar da condição "Caso não exista"... caso queira mesmo assim dar uma olhada em uma "IDE - Editor de Texto" para TypeScript, lhe recomendo o VS Code. Tenho colegas que usam o Brackets e WebStorm, mas não conheço suficiente bem para falar se é uma boa indicação.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, tem o [Everlaw na página do NetBeans](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/60605/typescript-editor). Não o conheço, não sei se é bom. Também achei [mais um *plugin*](https://github.com/GeertjanWielenga/TypeScript)

Porém IDE para TypeScript não falta.

O [Visual Studio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40609/101) é o mais óbvio. O [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) também é muito bom. tem o [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) que é bem mais simples, mas roda em várias plataformas.

Tem três *plugins* para Eclipse [[1](https://github.com/palantir/eclipse-typescript), [2](https://github.com/angelozerr/typescript.java), [3](http://typecsdev.com/)]. Tem o [Atom](https://atom.io/packages/atom-typescript), o [ALM](http://alm.tools/), o [Sublime Text](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Sublime-Plugin), o [Emacs](https://github.com/ananthakumaran/tide), e dois destacadores de sintaxe para Vim [[1](https://github.com/leafgarland/typescript-vim), [2](https://github.com/HerringtonDarkholme/yats.vim)] e outros dois serviços de linguagem [[1](https://github.com/Quramy/tsuquyomi), [2](https://github.com/clausreinke/typescript-tools.vim)].

Comment: O Everlaw parece que Everlaw só está disponível para versão 8.0.

Comment: Achei outro, de qualquer forma normalmente é para rodar em outras versões menores.