# Posso utilizar o C# (através do Visual Studio) para desenvolver um programa para Mac/OSX?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, osx, mac

Gostaria de saber se o Visual Studio (através de um computador rodando Windows e da linguagem C#) pode criar um programa administrativo (simples, para 1 usuário, envolvendo apenas uma interação com banco de dados) para um computador rodando Mac/OSX. Se sim, quais as configurações preciso definir na IDE para tal finalidade (recentemente formatei meu notebook e baixei o VS 2017, porém não sei quais opções na instalação devo marcar ou não, logo abandonei a instalação e recorri ao Stack antes de prosseguir).

Como mencionei, existe alguma especificação especial para um banco de dados simples nesse SO? Quais ferramentas devo utilizar para tal?

Ps: a pessoa não especificou o SO, porém sou completamente leigo em Mac/OSX

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 5):

Sim, é possível através do [Xamarin Platform](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/xamarin?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Você pode usar o [Visual Studio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40609/101) tradicional, mas ele não dá muito suporte ao Mac e vai sofrer. Provavelmente preferirá o Xamarin Studio no Mac mesmo. Tem os [requerimentos no site do produto](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/get-started/requirements?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Agora existe o [Visual Studio for Mac](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/mac/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

E lá no site tem [documentação para começar aprender configurar tudo e começar o desenvolvimento](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/mac/get-started/hello-mac?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Não dá para colocar tudo aqui.

Comment: Xamarin não seria só para mobile?

Comment: @Francisco tem pra Mac também: https://www.xamarin.com/platform

Answer (score 2):

Sim. Já existe o Visual Studio for Mac. Um IDE gratuito e completo para a criação de aplicativos modernos para Android, iOS e macOS, bem como aplicativos Web e serviços de nuvem. A versão Community é gratuita e é destinada à estudantes, desenvolvedores individuais e de software livre. Contém quase todos os recursos das versões pagas.

[Aqui está o link](https://www.visualstudio.com/pt-br/vs/visual-studio-mac/?rr=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.br%2F)