# É possível desenvolver uma aplicação em C++ no Visual Studio para rodar em Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio

Tenho que desenvolver uma aplicação para Linux em C++ e queria saber se é uma boa usar o Visual Studio 2017 no Windows para tal tarefa?

Queria saber os prós e contras, pois vi que o VS possui uma extensão para tal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se é uma boa é uma questão de opinião e vou me abster.

É possível e muita gente faz. O C++ da Microsoft atende o padrão C++17 (o último deste ano) em quase 100% e, se não me engano, já 100% do C++14 ou pelo menos do C++11, o que poucas pessoas usam tudo isto que acabou de entrar na padrão.

O C++ vem com o Visual Studio e pode muito bem usá-lo. Algumas pessoas gostam de usar o [Resharper C++](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper-cpp/) com complemento, ainda que ele tenha custo. Lembrando que o [VS Community é bem completo e gratuito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40609/101).

O compilador C++ permite fazer geração de executável *cross platform*, então mesmo no Windows pode gerar o executável para o Linux. É possível até mesmo depurar remotamente a aplicação no Linux. Mas ainda já é possível rodar o executável Linux no próprio Windows atual (tecnicamente é um *container* com um Ubuntu). Mas pode depurar como executável Windows e só no final gerar um executável Linux. Se fizer código portável, o recomendado, é tranquilo.

Pra meu fluxo de trabalho é como eu faria, principalmente a última opção.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Isso a algum tempo atras era impensavel! Linux e Windows era tipo agua e oleo, nao se misturavam. Sera que vamos ter um sistema operacional totalmente hibrido futuramente?

Comment: Não, mas vão trabalhar cada vez mais juntos.

Answer (score 1):

Mesmo com a facilidade da compilação [multiplataforma](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplataforma) oferecida pelo *Visual Studio 2017*, ainda sim seria necessário uma implementação específica para cada sistema operacional.

Isso acontece pois os sistemas operacionais que implementam o padrão [POSIX](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) (tais como o Windows e o Linux), fornecem [interfaces de programação (APIs)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_de_programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_aplica%C3%A7%C3%B5es) diferentes.

Mesmo utilizando uma linguagem de programação bastante [portável](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portabilidade_(inform%C3%A1tica)) tal como o C++, ainda sim seria necessário a implementação de um código específico para interagir com cada uma das APIs dos diversos sistemas operacionais existentes.

O mesmo acontece com a etapa de [depuração](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depura%C3%A7%C3%A3o), que **sempre** acontece em [tempo de execução](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempo_de_execu%C3%A7%C3%A3o) e sempre será feita de formas "não ortodoxas".

Se a questão da portabilidade e da compilação multiplataforma for um fator muito importante e relevante para seu projeto, *talvez* JAVA seja uma linguagem mais adequada do que o C++, o que descarta todas as complexidades aqui citadas.