# O que é linguagem de programação, IDE e compilador?

Tags: terminologia, ide, independente-de-linguagem, compiladores, ciência-da-computação

Iniciar em programação nem sempre é fácil, além de termos que aprender a "escrever o código", existem dezenas de termos, tecnologias, entre outras coisas que precisam ser estudadas.

Visando ajudar quem está começando, minha pergunta é: o que é uma linguagem de programação, uma IDE e um compilador? Qual a relação entre esses itens?

Comment: +1. Vai ajudar muitas pessoas novatas ;)

Comment: Essa é a intenção @WallaceMaxters Eu até iria postar direto com resposta, mas acho que tem muita gente aqui no site que pode dar uma resposta boa (inclusive melhor que uma minha).

Comment: +1. Foi uma ótima pergunta :D

Comment: Relacionado: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4617/101

Answer (score 87, accepted):

## TL;DR

Linguagem de programação é um conceito mais abstrato, são as regras [especificadas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111284/101) que regem como um código deve se comportar para produzir programas de computador. A linguagem não é um programa que executa.

Compilador é o que concretiza a linguagem de programação, é o que aplica estas regras e transforma o que um humano entende no código que a máquina entende e é capaz de executar. É um programa de transformação. Normalmente ele é um programa que roda em console através da linha de comando.

IDE é uma ferramenta (um software) que ajuda todo processo de desenvolvimento de software integrando outras ferramentas e facilitando seu uso. A principal função dele é o editor de texto.

Hoje em dia é muito comum as pessoas, principalmente quando estão começando a programar, não entenderem muito bem todos os aspectos do que envolve o processo de desenvolvimento de software, toda teoria da computação, e o papel de cada ferramenta neste processo. **IDE não é a linguagem de programação**.

## IDE

Como as pessoas começam como usuários de computador onde o normal é usar um Microsoft Word por exemplo, e aquilo faz tudo o que ele precisa em termos de edição de texto, quando ela vai programar e mandam ela instalar o [Visual Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio), o [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software)), o [Android Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio) ou algum outro IDE ela acha que aquilo é a linguagem de programação.

O IDE (Integreted Development Environment) é o ambiente de desenvolvimento integrado (note que é masculino), ou seja, é o programa que integra as várias ferramentas necessárias para o desenvolvimento de softwares ajudando todo o processo ficar mais fácil.

Sua principal função é ajudar o programador editar o código que será usado para criar seu programa.

Outra coisa muito importante que todos IDEs fazem é chamar o compilador, ou interpretador, dentro de certos parâmetros para gerar e/ou executar o programa criado se ele não contiver erros.

Ele também ajuda:

- depurar programas durante a execução com várias facilidades;
- gerenciar os projetos e suas configurações
- executar testes, montar o *deploy* ou até mesmo fazê-lo;
- fazer análise estática;
- controlar de versão;
- acessar banco de dados;
- gerar códigos automaticamente para certos padrões de codificação, como telas e relatórios;
- dar acesso fácil à documentação;
- diversas ajudas durante o processo de edição do código.

Isso pode variar de IDE para IDE e como ele está configurado. Como o nome diz, estas ferramentas costumam ser integradas. Claro que algumas estão lá por padrão, mas muitas delas dependem de um programa externo para executar a tarefa. O próprio compilador da linguagem normalmente é algo externo.

Um IDE pode suportar várias linguagens (ter ferramentas específicas para apoiar o uso de determinada linguagem).

## Compilador

O [compilador](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) é o programa que analisa e gera o executável do que está sendo criado. Ele pega um texto compreensível por humanos - o que o programador escreveu - e transforma em código compreensível por máquinas, um código binário que possui [instruções do que o processador deve executar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/142289/101) (há casos de código intermediário).

Obviamente ele não é um programa mágico, especial. Ele é apenas um processador de dados como tantos outros. Ele lê textos e os transforma. De uma certa forma é um programa relativamente simples. Claro que há complexidade em interpretar toda a gramática de uma linguagem e cada uma tem seu grau de complexidade.

Durante esse processo erros sintáticos e semânticos são verificados, otimizações podem ser feitas, e uma geração de novo código alvo é realizada.

Em alguns casos é possível interpretar este código ao invés do processo tradicional de compilação, ainda que a interpretação envolva um processo de compilação interno.

O compilador deve entender as regras que uma determinada linguagem de programação foi construída, e deve garantir que todas elas foram seguidas transformando o código escrito obedecendo estas regras.

Em geral o compilador é um programa de console, mas há casos que eles são bibliotecas que podem ser usadas em conjunto com outros programas.

Existem compiladores que suportam várias linguagens, ainda que costume existir uma certa separação (em geral há uma plataforma de compilação única mas compiladores diferentes).

Entenda [Como é feito um compilador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104814/101).

## Linguagem de programação

A [linguagem de programação](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language) é este conjunto de regras. É o que define a sintaxe e semântica a ser obedecida. Assim como toda língua natural, mas neste caso é uma língua mais limitada, mais lógica e com um propósito específico.

Estas linguagens podem ser C, C++, C#, Java, BASIC, COBOL, Fortran, Pascal, Go, D, PHP, JavaScript, Python, Ruby, Perl, Lua, Lisp, Haskell, etc.

Existem tantas porque cada uma possui um ponto forte, além de atender melhor um tipo de problema específico, atende gostos de pessoas diferentes. Há casos que não é bem a linguagem em si que a torna viável para um problema mas sim a infraestrutura que foi montada em torno dela.

Este conjunto de regras é definido por uma gramática e provavelmente uma especificação formal, ainda que alguns casos mais específicos a implementação do compilador é que define como a linguagem se comporta. Em geral isto ocorre em linguagens não padronizadas e que só possuem apenas um compilador para ela.

Entenda [Como é desenvolvida uma linguagem de programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124436/101).

É comum os compiladores não seguirem a especificação 100%, em geral por falha, ou mais ainda, por adicionar capacidades que a especificação não determina. Evidentemente isto é a exceção, caso contrário começaria se transformar em outra linguagem.

[Nem todas linguagens são de programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102452/101).

## Onde você programa?

Você usa o IDE para facilitar o trabalho de desenvolvimento, mas ele é apenas um facilitador e não pode ser confundido com a linguagem de programação. Qualquer problema que você está tendo com o código que está escrevendo é um problema com a linguagem e não com o IDE. Fazendo uma comparação com outras línguas, se você não sabe como escreve uma palavra em português ou como construir uma frase não pode dizer que isto é uma dificuldade que está tendo com o Word, é uma dificuldade com o português.

Um problema com o IDE ocorre durante o processo geral de desenvolvimento, quando algo falha ou a dificuldade encontrada é no IDE você tem um problema nele. Comparando novamente, quando você não está conseguindo fazer um parágrafo no Word, é uma dificuldade com o Word.

Quando alguma das ferramentas usadas falham ou você encontra dificuldade isoladamente você tem um problema nela especificamente. Isso pode ser até o compilador, mas raramente um problema é do compilador em si.

A maior parte das falhas ou dificuldades que a pessoa encontra durante o processo é durante o processo de compilação, mas porque o código tem algum problema, não porque o IDE ou o compilador não estão funcionando. Então o problema é com a linguagem de programação.

E não, o *bug* não está no IDE ou no compilador. O *bug* está no seu código escrito. É mais fácil acertar na loteria do que uma pessoa iniciante em programação achar um *bug*, principalmente no compilador, impedindo o uso correto da linguagem.

Um IDE pode usar compiladores diferentes, não só para linguagens diferentes, mas também para a mesma linguagem. A linguagem é única (ainda que possa ter dialetos), os compiladores não, e IDE menos ainda. O fato da maioria das pessoas usarem um determinado IDE para uma linguagem não o torna como parte da linguagem.

Um IDE é totalmente desnecessário para usar uma linguagem de programação (bem, pode existir alguma linguagem esotérica que exija). O compilador é absolutamente necessário, ainda que em alguns casos ele seja mais um interpretador.

## Exemplos de compiladores e IDEs

#### C/C++

Compiladores como o [GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) suportam linguagens como C, C++, Objective C, Fortran, Java (é muito raro alguém usá-lo para ela) e outras. Note que o GCC é apenas um dos compiladores existentes para as linguagens C e C++. Ele funciona em todas plataformas *mainstream* e várias outras. Entenda por plataforma, a arquitetura do processador ou sistema operacional. Em algumas pode exigir uma distribuição diferenciada, como é o caso do Windows. Neste sistema operacional costuma-se usar o [MinGW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW), mas no fundo o compilador é o GCC. Há quem use também a distribuição [Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin), mas á raro.

As linguagens C e C++ são padronizadas e possuem diversos compiladores que atendem suas especificações. Entre eles o [Clang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang), [Visual C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang) (Note que ele não chama Visual Studio C++ que seria o IDE para esta linguagem, apesar do nome, o compilador funciona em linha de comando e não tem nada de visual, esta parte fica no IDE) e [Intel C++ Compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_C%2B%2B_Compiler), só para citar os mais conhecidos e ativos.

[Code::Blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code::Blocks) é um dos IDEs "independentes" mais usados. Quem usa a biblioteca Qt costuma usar o [Qt Creator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_Creator). Há quem goste do [CodeLite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodeLite), [C++Builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2BBuilder), ou [XCode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode). [CLion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#CLion) começa ter adeptos.

Estas são linguagens onde há abundância de IDEs e todos importantes os que permitem o uso de várias linguagens oferecem algum nível de suporte a elas, em algum nível. Infelizmente há alguns bem ruins indicados em cursos (Dev C++, cof cof).

#### Java

Java é outra linguagem que possui diversos compiladores. O mais conhecido é o [disponibilizado pela Oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_compiler). Alguns fogem um pouco do padrão e há controvérsias se ele deveria ser chamado de compilador de Java, até a Microsoft já teve um. Outro bem conhecido é o compilador para o Android que tem características próprias. Além do Eclipse e Android Studio, já citados, o [NetBeans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans) é muito usado com esta linguagem ou C/C++. [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) é outra.

#### C#

C# possui o antigo compilador, o [novo que agora é uma plataforma de compilação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82756/101), e o compilador do [Mono](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_(software)). O Visual Studio é o IDE mais usado para esta linguagem, mas existem outros, como o [SharpDevelop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SharpDevelop) ou [MonoDevelop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MonoDevelop). Hoje é o [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) é muito usado, para outras linguagens também.

#### BASIC

BASIC tem diversos dialetos, cada um com seu próprio compilador. Mas dialeto pode ser diferente o suficiente para considerarmos como linguagens diferentes. [Visual BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic) é provavelmente o mais conhecido deles, e ele costuma rodar junto com o Visual Studio.

#### JavaScript

JavaScript costuma ser interpretado ou compilado na hora de sua utilização. Em geral isto é feito no navegador e cada um tem seu próprio compilador. [IE/Edge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chakra_(JScript_engine)), [Chrome/Opera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_(JavaScript_engine)), [Safari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit#JavaScriptCore), [etc.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ECMAScript_engines) A maioria dos IDEs citados suportam bem o JS, outro é o [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/).

#### PHP

PHP é uma linguagem interpretada. Existe uma plataforma oficial dele que pode ser complementada ou distribuída em formas diferentes. É raro uma distribuição diferente e principalmente uma implementação separada da oficial ter qualquer tipo de tração no mercado. Existem uma quantidade enorme de IDEs para PHP, mas é raro ter uma se destacando mais que outras.

#### Outras

Python e principalmente Ruby, possuem opções de compiladores, mas também não costumam ter muito sucesso. Diversos IDEs estão disponíveis, incluindo extensões para os IDEs citados mais acima, já que eles foram feitos para suportar diversas linguagens.

Há pelo menos um caso de [linguagem e IDE se confundindo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101695/101), ainda que sejam coisas diferentes, o Delphi.

Poderia continuar citando diversas outras linguagens com seus compiladores e IDEs, mas acho que isto dá uma boa base para depois ter perguntas mais específicas.

## IDEs *online*

Não sei se dá para chamar de IDE de verdade, mas tem várias que podem ser usadas para códigos rápidos como [ideone](https://ideone.com/), [repl.it](https://repl.it/), [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/), [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/), etc.

## Conclusão

É importante entender estas diferenças para se desenvolver melhor.

E é importante saber isto para usar as *tags* corretas e descrever melhor o problema. Não diga que seu problema é no IDE quando na verdade é no seu código escrito em determinada linguagem (use a *tag* da linguagem e não do IDE que está usando). O fato de usar um IDE, não costuma ajudar nada nestes casos. Apenas quando é algum problema que só pode ocorrer no seu uso.

É mais importante informar o compilador quando a linguagem costuma ter vários.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Se há alguma coisa errada na resposta, por favor me informe para que eu posso corrigir, é importante não ter nada errado informando as pessoas e eu quero melhorar o que está aqui.

Answer (score 60):

[image: Ensō, o símbolo da iluminação, força, elegância, o universo e o vazio]

<sub>Assim disse o Mestre Programador: *Sem o vento, a grama não se move. Sem software, o hardware é inútil.*</sub>

---

Algo misterioso é formado, nascido no vazio do silêncio. Aguardando só e imóvel, ele está ao mesmo tempo parado e ainda assim em constante movimento. Ele é a fonte de todos os programas. Eu não sei o seu nome, então o chamarei de Tao da Programação.

O Programador sonha com o Tao, e pela Linguagem seus sonhos ganham forma.

Suas mãos enlaçam o Tao, e pela IDE seus sonhos fluem para a Máquina.

No coração da Máquina, o Compilador transforma a Linguagem em instruções discretas.

As instruções controlam os rios de informação que escapam, rápidos e caudalosos, pelos barramentos de dados e além.

Se o Tao é grandioso, então a aplicação é grandiosa. Se a aplicação é grandiosa, então o Usuário tem prazer. Se o Usuário tem prazer, o Administrador está satisfeito, e existe harmonia no mundo.

O Tao da Programação flui para longe e retorna no vento da manhã.

Fontes: [1](http://canonical.org/~kragen/tao-of-programming.html#book4), [2](http://www.geocities.ws/worgtal/2002/tao.pdf)

Comment: Nunca o teu nick fez tanto sentido.

Comment: A reposta não responde à pergunta, e nem esclarece, e nem ajuda. Mas em meio à respostas que respondem, a sua resposta foi a que mais ventou.

Comment: Sua resposta é um deboche a uma pergunta completamente válida.

Comment: @Pablo Não vejo a resposta como um deboche. Definitivamente não é um conteúdo técnico, explicando em detalhes cada parte perguntada, mas dá um apanhado geral e bem-humorado sobre elas. Vejo como algo perfeitamente cabível, e até bem-vindo, para quebrar a monotonia volta e meia.

Comment: Acredito que os comentários existem para isso. Se não diz o que o AP quer saber, então não é uma resposta. Teria dado pra trabalhar melhor a resposta para atender aos dois requisitos: ser informativa e descontraída. Não foi isso que eu vi aqui.

Comment: @Pablo Não questiono a qualidade da resposta como um todo. Acredito também que ela poderia ser melhorada para atingir os 2 objetivos que você citou. Mas isso não significa que vejo a forma atual - com problemas e tudo - como um *deboche*

Comment: Infelizmente, eu vejo. Claro que isso não é algo objetivo e demonstrável, mas não acho que passa a imagem correta, do jeito que está. Se uma pessoa viu dessa forma, outras provavelmente verão. Não acho isso saudável.

Comment: É diferente, mas legal. Deu a cara pra bater e recebeu 13 votos positivos. Uma explicação baseada em história com símiles e metáforas. Na verdade, não vi nenhum tipo de humor nessa resposta, mas também não vi deboche. Se tem um atributo que eu não vi nessa resposta foi deboche. Tem até a fonte com mais exemplos desse tipo.

Comment: @Pablo não, acredito que você tenha interpretado de uma maneira que não a originalmente proposta. Ainda assim sua opinião é válida, e agradeço pelo *feedback*.

Comment: Um para o @Gabe em seu escuro trono foi o melhor de todos. 12mil em um ano e 10 meses, parabéns.

Comment: @EduardoSeixas Não entendi nada, mas se for pra ter um trono eu, particularmente, prefiro [esse](http://www.he-manreviewed.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/25-17-Reap-the-Reward-626x480.png)

Comment: @gabe é que menciono você no meu perfil. =)

Answer (score 40):

A linguagem de programação é um conjunto de palavras e simbolos que combinados criam instruções que são executadas por um dispositivo(computador, celular etc), basicamente a linguagem define as regras(sintaxe) de como as instruções devem ser montadas.

Compilador/analizador é o responsável por ler uma entrada(código da linguagem em texto puro), detectar todos os simbolos e/ou palavras chaves esse processo é conhecido como analise léxica, uma vez feito isso o próximo passo é  verificar se os símbolos respeitam a gramática da linguagem, em caso não exista nenhum problema o código pode ser interpretado ou será gerado um artefato(arquivo com a instruções convertidas para linguagem de maquina).

A IDE é uma ferramenta, para edição de código fonte de determinada linguagem de programação os principais recursos são highlight da sintaxe, auto complemente de instruções da linguagem. A IDE faz a ponta para ligar linguagem de programação com o compilador/interpretador, um exemplo onde isso fica bem evidente seria, utilizar C/C++ no windows, a linguagem seria o C/C++, o compilador geralmente é e o gcc(através do cwyng) e a IDE o eclipse ou o codeblocks.

Comment: Tem algum problema ou informação incorreta na resposta? posso corrigir/complementar.

Answer (score 24):

Em termos práticos e simples, segue:

- **linguagem de programação** é para a informática assim como o idioma é para os seres humanos - tem palavras, sintaxe, ortografia, etc.
- **compilador** é uma ferramenta que transforma seu código bonitinho em linguagem de máquina 00100111010101...
- **IDE** é como um bloco de notas avançado; ele vai indicar erros de sintaxe, colorir seu código como um lego para te facilitar identificar as peças, oferece gestão de arquivos do projeto e uma série de recursos bem legais dos quais vale mais a pena citar quando você começar a utilizar.

Comment: Muito boa sua resposta.

Comment: Obrigado. Procuro ser simples e prático, pois isso ajuda mais do que muita explicação técnica.

Answer (score 20):

Uma linguagem de programação é um método padronizado para comunicar instruções para um computador. É um conjunto de regras sintáticas e semânticas usadas para definir um programa de computador. Permite que um programador especifique precisamente sobre quais dados um computador vai atuar, como estes dados serão armazenados ou transmitidos e quais ações devem ser tomadas sob várias circunstâncias. Ex: C#, VB, Java, Python e etc.

IDE: IDE, do inglês *Integrated Development Environment* ou Ambiente de Desenvolvimento Integrado, é um programa de computador que reúne características e ferramentas de apoio ao desenvolvimento de software com o objetivo de agilizar este processo. Temos como exemplo o Visual Studio para .NET, Eclipse e Netbeans para Java e etc.

Um compilador é um programa de computador (ou um grupo de programas) que, a partir de um código fonte escrito em uma linguagem compilada, cria um programa semanticamente equivalente, porém escrito em outra linguagem, código objeto. Classicamente, um compilador traduz um programa de uma linguagem textual facilmente entendida por um ser humano para uma linguagem de máquina, específica para um processador e sistema operacional. Atualmente, porém, são comuns compiladores que geram código para uma máquina virtual que é, depois, interpretada por um interpretador.

Vale ressaltar que algumas linguagens de programação não possuem compilador, ou seja são interpretadas em tempo de execução.

Comment: Sobre linguagem de programação: Eu esperava mais.

Comment: dei uma melhorada em linguagem de programação. obrigado! :)

Comment: Sobre seu último parágrafo temos [essa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77070/20615) que fala exatamente isso. xD

Comment: Como o autor da resposta que você mencionou informa: "Claro que usar estes termos da pergunta não pode ser considerados totalmente errados já que todo mundo entende o seu significado" @Randrade, porém se possuir alguma terminologia de sugestão estou aberto para alterações.

Comment: Não quis dizer que era para adicionar em sua pergunta, me desculpe se deu a entender isso. Eu apenas postei pois foi mencionada por você. Quem ler poderá acessar, caso chame atenção.
Sobre sua resposta, só adicionaria a fonte de onde você retirou os significados.

Comment: Acredito que Delphi não deveria estar listado como linguagem de programação, visto que alguns dizem que Delphi é IDE utilizada para programar em pascal.

Comment: Tem uma pergunta agora mesmo falando sobre isso, acredito sim que delphi seja assim como IDE, também uma linguagem baseada em object-pascal. porém se você tiver algum material para leitura sobre o assunto, posso revisar o conteúdo e remover da resposta.

Comment: @Hoppy, o MiguelBatista foi o cara que acabou de fazer a pergunta :D

Comment: Vou remover logo delphi para não gerar polêmica, kk. Esse não é o foco do sopt.

Comment: Delphi é claramente uma IDE. Object pascal é a linguagem. Você pode compilar object pascal fora da IDE do Delphi. Basta achar o compilador (um EXE na pasta do Delphi) e compilar os arquivos. A IDE só facilita esse trabalho. O mesmo, obviamente, vale para C#, Java (com Eclipse ou IntelliJ). Portanto, eu colocaria Delphi somente como IDE.

Comment: @cantoni me parece que esta definição está ultrapassada, eu também achava http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101695/ide-e-linguagens-de-programa%c3%a7%c3%a3o

Comment: Entendi o seu argumento @bigown e faz sentido mesmo. Bom, independente disso, ainda posso compilar um código Delphi fora da IDE do Delphi e isso só reforça a ideia de que a IDE é um plus no ato de programar, mas não é fundamental. Acho importante essa separação. Inclusive, cito isso na minha resposta.

Comment: @cantoni sim, mas você ainda estará programa "em Delphi" :) Só depois que fui pesquisar para responder que descobri que tinha ocorrido essa transição de nomenclatura. Que faz sentido. Depois de pesquisar mais um pouco eu vou melhorar lá.

Comment: Sim @bigown, eu concordei com vc. Inclusve no meu ultimo comentário cito: "ainda posso compilar um código Delphi", ou seja assumi que a linguagem se chama Delphi e não Object Pascal. O que tentei foi reforçar a diferença entre Linguagem, IDE e compilador.

Answer (score 15):

Levando em consideração que o alvo são novatos (como bem observado por @Eduardo Seixas), procurem abstrair os seguintes conceitos:

> O que é linguagem de programação?

Algo como um [idioma](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%ADngua_natural) utilizado por programadores para se comunicar com uma máquina.

> O que é IDE?

Algo como um [Meio](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meios_de_comunica%C3%A7%C3%A3o) utilizado por programadores para se comunicar com uma máquina.

> O que é compilador?

Algo como um [dicionário](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dicion%C3%A1rio) utilizado por programadores para se comunicar com uma máquina.

**Resumindo**:

Para ser um [garoto de programa](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programador) é necessário se comunicar com a máquina (linguagem de programação e IDE), para que esta comunicação ocorra não pode haver erros (compilador), é tudo preto no branco e não existe espaço para meio certo (0 e 1).

Comment: Não concordo com a palavra idioma, com a palavra meio e com a palavra dicionário. Sua resposta não ajuda um novato, um aprendiz. Imagina ele procurando um idioma de uma linguagem de programação para aprender.

Comment: @Eduardo Seixas você está no seu direito de não concordar, mas tente manter sua mente aberta para o seguinte fato: Minha resposta é coerente com a pergunta em questão, simplesmente por cumprir com o objetivo além de estimular um dos fatores mais importantes da programação, a "**ABSTRAÇÃO**".

Answer (score 15):

**IDE**

IDE, do inglês Integrated Development Environment ou Ambiente de Desenvolvimento Integrado, é um programa de computador, que ao ser instalado em sua máquina, oferece recursos diversos que ajudam o desenvolvedor na sua tarefa de programação. Existe IDE paga e IDE open source. Não é necessário um IDE para desenvolver um sistema, apenas um simples bloco de notas é suficiente, pois bastam digitar as palavras coerentes com a linguagem de programação e o sistema estará pronto.

**LINGUAGEM DE PROGRAMAÇÃO**

A linguagem de programação(LP) é composta por uma sintaxe e semântica própria (formada por regras com letras, dígitos e símbolos dotados de significado) e um conjunto de normas restrito e tem o objetivo de dar instruções para uma máquina. Elas são linguagens que auxiliam aos programadores a escrever programas com maior facilidade e rapidez.

A sintaxe é responsável por definir como os programas podem auxiliar na resolução de conflitos dentro do computador. Além disso, executam outras funções como oferecer segurança, traduzir linguagens, trabalhar a comunicação e criar arquivos.

**COMPILADOR**

Um compilador é um programa especial que processa declarações escritas em uma linguagem de programação específica e os transforma em linguagem de máquina ou "código". Normalmente, um programador escreve declarações de linguagem em uma linguagem de programação, uma linha por vez usando um editor de texto ou IDE. Ao executar o compilador primeiro analisa todas as instruções de linguagem sintaticamente linha após linha e em seguida constrói o código de saída, certificando-se de que as declarações que se referem a outras declarações são referidos corretamente no código final.

Answer (score 11):

Para entender, vamos fazer uma analogia com o Português.

Para que consigamos nos comunicar uns com os outros no SOpt utilizamos o Português escrito. No Português (assim como em qualquer outra língua), existem dois conceitos muito importantes, que também são aplicados nas linguagens de programação, são eles: **sintaxe** e **semântica**.

Basicamente, sintaxe tem relação com a forma das palavras. Por "Ezemplo": "Existem várias linguajens de programassão. Qual escolher?".

O erro acima é identificado facilmente e este é um erro de sintaxe. "Ezemplo", "linguajens" e "programassão" são palavras que não existem na lingua Portuguesa.

Numa linguagem de programação como Java, a sintaxe é composta por várias palavras, como **if**, **else**, **class**, **while**, etc.

Já a semântica define o sentido. É a semântica que dá a compreensão quando você junta as palavras. Exemplos:

Amanhã no parque vou.
Amanhã vou no parque.
No parque amanhã vou.
Vou no parque amanhã.

Todas essas frases fazem sentido para você, pois o seu cérebro realiza um processo de interpretação e consegue entender o sentido.

Em Java, algumas frases de exemplo são:

```
if (a > 10) {
   System.out.println("a é maior do que 10");     
}
```

Porém, se escrevermos o mesmo assim:

```
System.out.println("a é maior do que 10") if (a > 10);
```

Isso, obviamente, não vai funcionar.

Isso acontece, pois uma Linguagem de Programação não será traduzida para código de máquina pelo ser humano, isso será feito por um **compilador**.

Portanto, um compilador é um software que recebe como entrada um texto escrito em uma linguagem de programação e traduz isso para outra linguagem, comumente chamada de linguagem de máquina (o famoso Assembly). Essa é a linguagem que o processador "entende".

Para que o processo de compilação ocorra sem erros, é necessário ter regras muito bem definidas para a sintaxe e semântica. Por isso, muita gente sofre com C quando aprende-se a programar, já que muitas regras devem ser seguidas, como ";" no final, abrir e fechar chaves, etc.

As palavras erradas e frases em Português que escrevi acima foram corretamente interpretadas, pois o nosso cérebro é muito mais flexível e adaptável, assim, aceita vários erros de sintaxe e semântica. Enfim, somos seres que temos inteligência, afinal de contas, quem criou os compiladores? :-) Já um compilador não, ele é extremamente rígido e se não seguirmos as suas regras, não conseguiremos utilizá-lo.

As IDEs, por sua vez, são softwares que tornam o processo de programar mais tranquilo, já que elas conseguem não só identificar os erros antes do processo de compilação, como dar dicas para que certas construções sejam feitas de formas diferentes. Importante: uma IDE não é fundamental para que consigamos programar. É perfeitamente possível programar em C, Java, C#, etc, utilizando um editor de texto qualquer e depois chamar o compilador passando esses arquivos para que sejam compilados.

Entretanto, as IDEs são muito utilizadas, pois permitem que o programador matenha o foco na resolução do problema, no negócio em si. A IDE se encarrega de ajudá-lo a identificar os erros e automatiza muitas tarefas, como o próprio processo de compilação. Dificilmente alguém programa sem IDE hoje em dia, pois programação ficou algo bem complexo, com várias camadas, várias linguagens, vários conceitos e aspectos distintos.

Pessoalmente, eu acho que as IDEs são fundamentais no dia-a-dia, mas não para iniciantes. Para os iniciantes as IDEs são prejudiciais. Digo isso, pois as IDEs fazem tudo parecer mágica. É tanta coisa automatizada que um iniciante não consegue enxergar a complexidade por trás de uma IDE. E, quem está começando a programar, deve ser exposto exatamente ao oposto, ou seja, deve programar usando um editor de texto e o compilador, para entender na carne que *não* existe mágica em computação.

Answer (score 4):

Gostei desse tópico.

De maneira resumida:

Linguagem de programação: É o conjunto de regras e convenções que se deve seguir para escrever código que será traduzido para linguagem de máquina.

Compilador: É o software que transforma código escrito em linguagem de programação para linguagem de máquina.

IDE: É um editor de texto com funcionalidades extras que ajudam os programadores a escrever código de maneira correta e eficiente. Entre as funcionalidades das IDEs mais sofisticadas estão: Indicar erros de digitação em tempo real para que sejam facilmente corrigidos, autocompletar durante digitação, segurar tecla e clicar em partes do código para navegar entre diferentes porções do mesmo e entre arquivos, *debugar* código avançando linha a linha, etc.

Relação entre linguagem de programação, IDE e compilador:

O programador escreve o código utilizando a linguagem de programação na IDE, esta por sua vez chama o compilador que transforma o código em linguagem de máquina.

Vou adicionar a explicação de alguns outros termos que também são muito perguntados pelos novatos:

Linguagem fracamente tipada:

São as linguagens em que o programador pode criar variáveis sem especificar previamente o tipo de dado que será armazenado nelas. PHP é um bom exemplo de linguagem fracamente tipada pois ao se criar uma variável não é necessário definir o tipo da mesma, embora inicializá-la com um valor adequado, mesmo não sendo necessário, pode ser visto como uma boa prática. O interpretador especifica o tipo baseado no conteúdo da variável.
Ex:   `$variavelstring = "";`   `$variavelinteiro=0;` 
Nota1: O tipo da variável muda toda vez que o conteúdo muda de tipo.
Nota2: Dizer que a linguagem é "fracamente tipada" **não** é a mesma coisa que dizer que a linguagem "não possui tipagem". Essa segunda afirmação é um erro comum que não deve ser cometido.

Linguagem fortemente tipada:

São as linguagens em que é necessário especificar o tipo de todas as variáveis na sua declaração. As variáveis não precisam ser inicializadas de imediato, mas a definição de seu tipo é necessária na declaração das mesmas.
O tipo das variáveis é imutável. Como exemplo de linguagem fortemente tipada temos o Java. Ex: `String variavelstring = "Teste";`  `int numero = 1;` `Meuobjeto obj;`

Obs: Um erro comum cometido por novatos em Java é o NullPointerException. Isso ocorre quando se tenta manipular um objeto que não foi inicializado ainda.

Errado: `Meuobjeto obj;   obj.toString();` ->  NullPointerException.

Certo: `Meuobjeto obj = new Meuobjeto();   obj.toString();`

Linguagem interpretada vs linguagem compilada:

Linguagem interpretada é aquela que o código não passa por compilação e são chamadas de linguagem de script. Ex: Javascript, PHP.
Linguagem compilada é aquela em que o código passa pelo processo de compilação, ou seja é transformado em código de máquina.

Java é interpretado ou compilado?

Essa é uma boa pergunta.
Java é uma linguagem compilada, mas seu código não é compilado para código de máquina e sim para `bytecodes` que são interpretados pela JVM (Java Virtual Machine), a máquina virtual java, que é um software responsável por executar os comandos compilados para bytecodes.

Comment: Legal a tua resposta, porém, a partir da parte em que você diz: "*Vou adicionar a explicação de alguns outros termos que também são muito perguntados pelos novatos [...]*" acho que a resposta perdeu o rumo.

Comment: Na verdade eu tinha escrito o que veio depois antes de tudo que estava acima. A parte de cima foi incluída pra atender a pergunta. ^_^!