# Erro "NullReferenceExeption was unhandled" ao compilar

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Segue o código abaixo:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        button1.Click += Button1_Click;
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal n1, n2, result;

        n1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        n2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);

        result = n1 + n2;

        MessageBox.Show("Resultado é " + result.ToString());
    }

}
```

Comment: Em que linha? Só com este trecho não dá para identificar onde está o problema. Este erro é sintoma de problema em outro lugar. Por falar nisto, você não está com problema no Visual Studio, entenda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/101703/101

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você excluiu o método [`InitializeComponent()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/245825/4190610) que deveria ser chamado no construtor do form. Esse método é declarado na outra parte da classe (note que a classe tem o modificador `partial`), provavelmente está num arquivo `Form1.Designer.cs`.

Basicamente o método `InitializeComponent()` instancia e cria todos os componentes no seu form, por isso essa `NullReferenceException` está estourando - a variável `button1` (assim como todos os outros componentes) não foi instanciada.

Seu construtor deve ficar assim:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    button1.Click += Button1_Click;
}
```

---

Embora não tenha nada a ver com o erro, é importante dizer que você não precisa declarar suas variáveis como `decimal`, você pode declará-las diretamente como `int`. Isso não vai causar grandes problemas, mas não vejo sentido para fazê-lo. Se você quer usar um número inteiro crie uma variável `int`.

Answer (score 3):

Felipe, 
o `NullRedferenceExeption` ocorre quando você tenta  fazer referência a um objeto (`NULO`) que não existe em seu código,  se isso ocorre nesse trecho de código com certeza é no `textBox1.Text`, `textBox2.Text` ou na chamada do `Click += new System.EventHandler`. o ideal é você **DEPURAR** seu código e ver o que esses controles tem no `Text`. [Veja mais detalhes aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/sxw2ez55(v=vs.80).aspx)

Veja como você pode corrigir isso.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            decimal n1, n2, result;

            n1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            n2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);

            result = n1 + n2;

            MessageBox.Show("Resultado é " + result.ToString());
        }              
    }
```