# Inserir data atual em um campo

Tags: c#, .net, string, microsoft-access, ado.net

Estou utilizando `dataAdapters` do .Net para criar um projeto como base de aprendizado de BD com C#. Escolhi um caminho mais fácil que seria trabalhar a maior parte do tempo no modo design através dos `Datasets`. A batalha que enfrento é para inserir a data atual em um campo do BD. O código à seguir trabalha bem com *strings* para os campos texto e `int` para os campos de chave estrangeira:

```
orcTableAdapter.Insert(Int32.Parse(comboBox2.ValueMember),datatime.Now, 0,Int32.Parse(comboBox1.ValueMember));
orcTableAdapter.Update(vorc2DataSet.Orcamento);
vorc2DataSet.AcceptChanges();
orcTableAdapter.Fill(vorc2DataSet.Orcamento);
```

Sei que existem formas de converter através de `Add.Parameters` mas não sei como adaptar a este formato sem ter que mudar todo o código.

Segue a mensagem de exceção:

> An unhandled exception of type System.FormatException occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: A cadeia de caracteres de entrada não estava em um formato correto.

Comment: Algumas coisas aí indicam que não está aprendendo do jeito certo, principalmente se preocupando com mudar código se isto for necessário. Mas neste caso específico esses *comboBox* devem conter dados  incompatíveis para gerar um inteiro. Não posso garantir com tão poucas informações. Enquanto leia sobre isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101. Seu problema não parece ser com o Visual Studio.

Comment: Algo me diz que você não leu minha questão com atenção também. Os dados das comboBox funcionam perfeitamente, o que não funciona é a minha tentativa de inserir a data e hora diretamente no BD através do comando padrão para forms do Visual Studio (DateTime.Now). Estou tentando solucionar este detalhe a mais de 8 horas e todo este tempo eu gastei com leitura. Eu ainda chego lá.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O único método usado neste trecho que produz esta exceção é o [`Int32.Parse()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Int32_Parse_System_String_), então o problema certamente está no conteúdo das variáveis dos *comboboxes* existentes. O que tem nelas devem ser possíveis de conversão para um número inteiro.

Aconselho evitar o uso de tecnologias obsoletas como `TableAdapter` e Access.

Comment: Amigo, você estava certo quanto ao Int32.Parse, mas o meu maior erro foi que ao procurar erro na data, acabei trocando o campo data de lugar no access e no wizard do data source ficou em ordem invertida. Segue o código corrigido para esclarecimento: orcTableAdapter.Insert(Convert.ToInt32(comboBox2.SelectedValue), DateTime.Now,Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedValue),0);
            orcTableAdapter.Update(vorc2DataSet.Orcamento);
            vorc2DataSet.AcceptChanges();
            orcTableAdapter.Fill(vorc2DataSet.Orcamento);