# Há alguma diferença entre compilar pelo terminal do linux ou pela IDE?

Tags: c, linux, terminal, ide

Estou programando em `C` no `linux` há um semestre já, e sempre me deparo com pessoas que se dizem melhores programadores porque compilam e executam o programa através do `terminal`. Porém, diante de várias  pesquisas, sempre encontrei na internet artigos dizendo que a `IDE` **foi feita para ajudar o programador, fazer com que o tempo que ele usaria compilando toda hora e rodando no terminal, melhorasse um pouco.**

Na minha humilde experiência com os dois, realmente, eu achei muito mais fácil apenas compilar e rodar pela `IDE`. Mas como estou iniciando nessa área, gostaria de saber de vocês qual a diferença? É melhor mesmo compilar pelo terminal? Se sim, porquê?

Observação: Utilizo o codeblock.

Comment: A pergunta é um bocado baseada em opiniões. Por exemplo aqui no meu trabalho compilamos a aplicação com um script previamente criado para executar comandos na linha de comandos. Dependendo do que pretende o IDE pode servir sim, desde que você saiba o que está a fazer, ou seja, como o IDE está a compilar o seu código. De resto é uma questão de gosto ou de necessidade.

Comment: Entendi Jorge B. Como as pessoas falam muito do terminal, eu pensei que seria algo  que era "o certo a se fazer". Obrigada ;)

Comment: Marcielli é mesmo só questão de gosto, claro que os geeks vão todos dizer que é melhor fazer *tudo* no terminal, mas tens o exemplo do Android Studio que faz tudo por nós e dá muito jeito. Mas para alguns casos específicos tem mesmo de ser a mão a compilação de uma app Android.

Comment: @MarcielliOliveira Sua pergunta é bastante válida, mas parece fugir do foco do site. Mas pra não te deixar sem resposta: saiba o que a IDE está fazendo por trás dos panos quando vc clica no botão de compilar. Assim que você aprender isso, use o botão de compilar. Não existe glória nenhuma em perder tempo. Ninguém vai ligar pro quanto seu desenvolvimento foi "nobre" se você não entregar resultados tão rápido quanto esperado.

Comment: @Pablo adorei essa última frase. Mais nada.

Comment: Compilar o programa pela linha de comando eu uso somente em casos específicos, geralmente quando faço acesso remoto em minha maquina, porque não consigo carregar a IDE em modo gráfico. Quando eu estou programando uso atalhos da IDE para compilar acho mais rápido e prático, mas não tem nenhum problema usar qualquer uma dessas opções.

Comment: Obrigada a todos. Entendo que não é o foco do site. Caso achem melhor, eu deleto. Sem problemas. De todo modo, me ajudaram bastante.

Comment: @MarcielliOliveira eu editei a pergunta, com aquele título acho que já fica mais dentro do escopo do site. Se não gostar da edição pode reverter. Mas acho que deve manter a pergunta, é bem interessante.

Comment: Gostei sim Jorge, achei melhor também. Obrigada.

Comment: Aqui tem informação relevante sobre isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Acredito que seja importante saber como funciona no terminal, mas a não ser que você vá utilizar comandos muito específicos para compilar não há necessidade.

Toda IDE foi feita com o intuito de agilizar e ajudar o trabalho do programador, sendo que muitas delas permite que você passe parâmetros antes da compilação.

Existem diversos fatores que diferenciam um bom e um "mal" programador, escrever um  `gcc prog.c -o prog`  não é assim tão diferente de apertar o play na IDE.

Comment: A IDE ajuda especialmente a retirar a parte mecânica do desenvolvimento e deixar o programador livre para se dedicar ao que softwares não conseguem fazer sozinhos.

Comment: Exatamente :) Tem muita gente que acha que fazer da maneira mais complicado o torna melhor, sendo que poderiam gastar este tempo melhorando o que realmente interessa em seus projetos.

Comment: O seu ultimo comentário foi quase tão bom quanto a resposta +1 nos dois :)

Answer (score 2):

A diferença é mais humana que física. Um programa compilado em um IDE pode até sofrer de algumas poucas diferenças devido aos parâmetros "genéricos" de compilação do IDE porém a maioria das pessoas não conhecem muitos parâmetros de seus compiladores para acrescentar algo e aqui aparece a diferença humana de se programar sem IDE: *o conhecimento das ferramentas que o IDE usa, do processo de compilação e link edição.*

Porém a vida é curta e o mercado restrito. **Ficar lendo a documentação do GCC e do Linker pode ser uma perda de tempo e dinheiro.**

Eu só precisei aprender mais sobre as ferramentas de geração de código quando algo dava errado ou um IDE era muito caro e uma alternativa custom era possível, dessa forma gosto do misto IDE leve e terminal como Code::Blocks + Guake (terminal suspenso) para programar sistemas embarcados e descarto os IDEs de base Eclipse e não tenho grana para um IAR.