# Como um CheckBox pode receber um DataGridView CheckBoxCell

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

No meu DataGridView traz do Banco de Dados as informações do usuário, dentre elas se ele é administrador ou não, esta celula tem um DataGridViewCheckBoxCell.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero passar o valor dela (True/False) para um CheckBox Control. Tentei usar o seguinte código, mas não funciona.

Debugando, percebi que a variável adm sempre é True, mesmo vindo False do Banco e o CheckBox mesmo recebendo o valor, não é marcado, nada acontece.

O CheckBox esta por padrão com o CheckState **Indeterminate**

```
 private void tsbEditarUsuario_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (gridConsultaUsuario.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
            {
                ucEditarUsuario editarUsuario = new ucEditarUsuario();
                editarUsuario.txtNome_detalhe.Text = gridConsultaUsuario.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                editarUsuario.txtUserCadastro_detalhe.Text = gridConsultaUsuario.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                editarUsuario.txtEmail_detalhe.Text = gridConsultaUsuario.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                editarUsuario.cboSetor_detalhe.SelectedItem = gridConsultaUsuario.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                editarUsuario.cboCargo_detalhe.SelectedItem = gridConsultaUsuario.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();

                var adm = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)this.gridConsultaUsuario.CurrentRow.Cells[5];

                editarUsuario.chkAdm_consulta.Checked = adm.Selected;
                _tabSystem.subTab(telaPrincipal.tabPrincipal.SelectedIndex, editarUsuario);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Selecione um usuário");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Gabriel, só pra constar, você não precisa utilizar a tag `visual-studio` quando o problema não for explicitamente com a IDE. Se lhe interessar, leia [O que é linguagem de programação, IDE e compilador?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/18246)

Comment: Só com esse trecho de código fica difícil sabe onde esta o erro.

Comment: Mas o que mais é necessário? Posso postar o método inteiro mas não sei se faz diferença.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após pesquisar um pouco, consegui resolver o problema.

```
editarUsuario.chkAdm_consulta.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(gridConsultaUsuario.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString().ToLower());
```

Answer (score 1):

**Tente**:

```
int index = gridConsultaUsuario.SelectedRows[0].Index;
ckAdm.Checked= Convert.ToBoolean(gridConsultaUsuario.Rows[index].Cells[5].Value);
```