# Definir multiplos estilos para um UserControl através de StaticResource's no WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Estou começando a trabalhar com WPF por causa da sua semelhança com o HTML. Percebi através das minhas pesquisas que quando eu utilizo uma expressão como essa `Style="{StaticResource MeuStyle}"` se parece muito com uma definição de classes que tenho no html (`class="MeuStyle"`).

É possível mesclar diversos estilos em uma só StaticResource para que essa seja aplicada sobre o Style daquele componente? Minha intenção é trabalhar semelhante ao bootstrap, onde eu defino 2 classes em um button assim:

**Em HTML**

```html
<button class="btn">MeuButton</button>
<button class="btn btn-success">MeuButton</button>
<button class="btn btn-error">MeuButton</button>
```

**Em WPF ~ (o que eu preciso)**

```xaml
<Button Content="Button" Style="{StaticResource btn}"/>
<Button Content="Button" Style="{StaticResource btn, btnSuccess}"/>
<Button Content="Button" Style="{StaticResource btn, btnError}"/>
```

Comment: Você não precisa usar a tag `visual-studio` quando o problema não tiver nenhuma relação com a IDE. Caso tenha alguma dúvida sobre isso, leia [esta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/18246)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é possível especificar mais de um *resource* utilizando o [`StaticResource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms750950(v=vs.100).aspx) e nem o [`DynamicResource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms748942(v=vs.100).aspx), mas o que você pode fazer, e que também é o recomendado, é criar um estilo e depois criar um outro que se baseie no primeiro através da propriedade [`Style.BasedOn`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1).

Veja um exemplo:

```
<Style x:Key="Style1">
  <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="Yellow"/>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="Style2" BasedOn="{StaticResource Style1}">
  <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
</Style>
```

No exemplo acima o `Style2`, se aplicado a um elemento, irá aplicar a alteração de `Control.Background` do `Style1` e a alteração de `Control.Foreground` do `Style2` em si, dessa forma você consegue um efeito parecido com herança e que parece ser o que você procura.

Comment: Isso mesmo parceiro, publiquei isso a algum tempo e esqueci rsrsrs, mas valeu a intenção