# Regra revisão de código Visual Studio ou Eclipse

Tags: c#, vb.net

Gostaria de saber se existe algum Add-in para visual studio que garante que enquanto eu estiver em ambiente de desenvolvimento faça alguma alteração porém quando eu gerar o build do projeto, essa parte comentada seja revisada me avisando que em produção não irá funcionar

Exemplo:

```
// DESENVOLVIMENTO
string servidor = "umaString";

// PRODUÇÃO
string servidor = "outraString";
```

As vezes é necessário realizar esses comentários e forçar certas ações só em ambiente de desenvolvimento mas quando gero build as vezes acabo esquecendo de reverter essa alteração e tenho retrabalho

Desde já agradeço

Comment: Guilherme, você não precisa colocar a tag `visual-studio` quando seu problema não tem relação com a IDE. Veja essa pergunta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/18246

Comment: E, respondendo sua pergunta, você pode ter esse efeito usando o pré-processamento, com `#if DEBUG`.

Comment: kkk verdade jbueno. Parabéns pra você
Obrigado

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o operador #if DEBUG para isto, conforme demonstrado na documentação da Microsoft:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/4y6tbswk.aspx

Não é necessário definir a variável DEBUG, pois o próprio Visual Studio já faz isso, quando você compila um executável como DEBUG, ele já define esta variável internamente, caso contrário a mesma não é definida. Você também pode definir outras variáveis para inúmeros casos que você necessite.

```
// exemplo definindo a variável MYTEST, que também pode ser usada para verificações adicionais
#define MYTEST
using System;
public class MyClass 
{
    static void Main() 
    {
#if (DEBUG && !MYTEST)
        Console.WriteLine("DEBUG is defined");
#elif (!DEBUG && MYTEST)
        Console.WriteLine("MYTEST is defined");
#elif (DEBUG && MYTEST)
        Console.WriteLine("DEBUG and MYTEST are defined");
#else
        Console.WriteLine("DEBUG and MYTEST are not defined");
#endif
    }
}
```

Comment: Se definir DEBUG, ele não será sempre `true`?

Comment: Já ajustei na resposta, vai depender de como você esta gerando a versão, se gerar como Release a variável DEBUG não é definida, se gerar como Debug, a mesma será sempre definida.

Comment: Veja, você está definindo `DEBUG`. Nesse caso, mesmo que eu execute como `Release` o código será executado, porque existe uma instrução explícita para definir `DEBUG` (`#define DEBUG`). Consegues entender?

Comment: sim, vou editar a resposta novamente para ver se fica mais claro.

Comment: Opa, eu não tinha visto a edição. Está certinho =) +1