# Conexão entre Entity Framework e Sybase 12

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, sybase

Pessoal to tentando fazer uma conexão com visual studio 2015, utilizando o C# e usando o entity Framework e o sybase 12, já virei a internet e não achei nenhuma solução se alguém souber algo por favor me ajude!

Comment: Apenas uma dica: Você não precisa usar a tag `visual-studio` quando sua pergunta não tem relação com a IDE. Se tiveres dúvida sobre isso, veja [essa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/18246). Você não está tentando fazer uma conexão entre o Visual Studio e o Sybase, você está tentando fazer uma conexão com uma linguagem de programação (C#, VB.NET, etc.) e o Sybase.

Comment: Opa, ta certo valeu!

Comment: Faltou você dizer qual a linguagem que está usando...