# Nomenclatura de variáveis e metodos no c#

Tags: c#, variáveis

Olá pessoal hoje notei algo curioso em trecho de código aqui na empresa

Veja :

```
  private void Cadastro_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Acao) && Acao.Equals("Editar"))
            {
                CarregarInformações();
            }
        }
```

Reparou no `CarregarInformações();`

Sempre fui orientado a não utilizar os caracteres especiais para nomear variáveis e métodos. mas não sei a explicação por trás disso tudo , este fato me deixou ainda mais curioso , afinal por que e permitida a escrita dessa forma sendo que isso não e uma boa pratica ?

Comment: Qual é a fonte que diz que é má prática? Lá tem uma explicação do motivo? Se não souber o porquê de alguma coisa, não acredite naquilo. Acreditar em boas práticas não é uma boa prática :P

Comment: @jbueno juro que tentei achar aqui rs esse assunto vlws =D

Comment: Tranquilo @stringnome. Duplicadas são boas para o site, talvez outras pessoas venham a pesquisar como você pesquisou e agora elas acharão a resposta correta =D. Uma questão importante é que você tocou no assunto "boas práticas" e, talvez, isso possa fazer com que sua pergunta seja diferente da outra...

Comment: Outra coisa importante @stringnome. Você não precisa usar a tag `visual-studio` quando a pergunta não tiver nenhuma relação com a IDE. Veja [essa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/18246)

Comment: @jbueno está Ok

Comment: C# tem suporte para os caracteres especiais, só que algumas linguagens não tem, nesse caso, se precisar fazer alguma integração com um modelo de C# que usa caracteres especiais isso pode causar alguns problemas com a outra linguagem.