# Texto dentro de uma picturebox

Tags: .net, winforms, vb.net

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero fazer isso nas `PictureBoxes` pra quando eu passar o mouse ela mostrar a mensagem que eu escrevi.

Como posso fazer?

Lembrando utilizo a versão *Visual Basic 2010*

Comment: Bruno, você não precisa usar a tag `visual-studio` nesse tipo de pergunta. Veja bem, o Visual Studio é apenas a ferramenta (IDE) que você usa para programar (C#, VB.NET, F#, etc.), seu problema é em `VB.NET`, logo é esta tag que deverias usar. Se tiveres confuso quanto a isso, dê uma lida nas respostas [desta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/18246)

Comment: eu botei ,a tag ,visual-basic-2010,axo que bugou

Comment: Você deve ser se confundido, porque esta tag não existe. Mas enfim, já está corrigido, só quis lhe informar mesmo =D. A resposta serviu para você?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar um *ToolTip* para isso.

Primeiramente arraste um `ToolTip` da *ToolBox* para o seu form - ele não será mostrado dentro do form, e sim num rodapé, veja a imagem
[image: Footer do form - visual studio]

Agora **todos** os componentes do form têm uma propriedade chamada `ToolTip on toolTip1 (ou qualquer que seja o nome do ToolTip que foi adicionado anteriormente`.

#### Pronto.

Agora só é necessário definir essa propriedade com o texto que queres que apareça na *ToolTip*.