# Erro em compilação no Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015

Sou muito novo em Visual Studio, estou tentando compilar um server e me retorna milhares de erros parecidos com estes:

```
1>int_guild.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _strtoi64 referenced in function inter_guild_exp_parse_row
1>libcmtd.lib(_init_.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CrtDbgReport referenced in function _CRT_RTC_INIT
1>libcmtd.lib(_init_.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CrtDbgReportW referenced in function _CRT_RTC_INITW
1>libcmtd.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _seh_filter_exe referenced in function "int `int __cdecl __scrt_common_main_seh(void)'::`1'::filt$0" (?filt$0@?0??__scrt_common_main_seh@@YAHXZ@4HA)
1>libcmtd.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _set_app_type referenced in function "int __cdecl pre_c_initialization(void)" (?pre_c_initialization@@YAHXZ)
1>libcmtd.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __setusermatherr referenced in function "int __cdecl pre_c_initialization(void)" (?pre_c_initialization@@YAHXZ)
1>libcmtd.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _configure_narrow_argv referenced in function "public: static int __cdecl __scrt_narrow_argv_policy::configure_argv(void)" (?configure_argv@__scrt_narrow_argv_policy@@SAHXZ)
1>libcmtd.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _initialize_narrow_environment referenced in function "void __cdecl initialize_environment(void)" (?initialize_environment@@YAXXZ)
1>libcmtd.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _initialize_narrow_environment
```

Alguém sabe ou tem ideia do que pode ser?

Comment: Provavelmente está faltando especificar um arquivo que tenha estes símbolos e que estão sendo usado no seu código, direta ou indiretamente. De qualquer forma seria bom dar uma lida nisso para entender melhor com o que está trabalhando: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101

Comment: @bigown é um server de um jogo, conheço mais de Java, eu sinceramente não sei o que fazer.

Comment: Muito provavelmente porque está querendo construir a casa sem fazer o alicerce. Sempre fica complicado.

Comment: Isso nao é exactamente um erro do compilador: isso é um erro do *linker*. O codigo que tens faz referencia as funcoes reportadas, mas o *linker* nao as consegue encontrar nas bibliotecas instaladas a que ele tem acesso. Solucao: descobre em que biblioteca(s) estao essas funcoes e faz com que o *linker* trabalhe com ela(s). Por exemplo, quando usas a funcao `printf()` o *linker* sabe onde a encontrar (nao, nao é em `<stdio.h>` que é apenas um header).