# Como ocultar processo ao clicar no button

Tags: vb.net

Eu gostaria de saber se é possível eu pegar o id de um programa como no exemplo
e ocultar ele (sendo que ele já esta aberto), tirando ele da barra de navegação (https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4AA5.png), ou seja, ao clicar no botão ele oculta o programa, porém continua rodando normalmente e oculto. Eu ainda não tentei nada pois ainda não entendi como fazer.

Comment: Você não precisa colocar a tag `visual-studio` quando o problema não tiver relação com a IDE. Veja [esta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/18246) para maiores detalhes.

Comment: Explique melhor o que você pretende fazer? Ocultar uma aplicação de terceiros? Ou abrir a sua aplicação "minimizada"?

Comment: ocultar aplicação de terceiro, não apenas minimizar também, eu sei como abrir oculta, porém não sei ocultar quando já aberta .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem diversas maneiras de fazer isso, mas aqui está uma das mais fáceis.

Principalmente, referencie essa namespace:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
```

Agora, declare essa função.

```
<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function ShowWindow(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal nCmdShow As Integer) As Boolean
End Function
```

E use esse método para exibir ou esconder algo.

```
Public Sub AlterarStatus(ByVal NomeDoProcesso$, ByVal Status As Integer)
    Dim mywindow As Integer
    Dim processRunning As Process() = Process.GetProcesses()
    For Each pr As Process In processRunning
        ' Uso do ToLower() para ignorar maiúsculas de minúsculas, se não quiser isso, remova
        ' nos dois membros
        If pr.ProcessName.ToLower() = NomeDoProcesso.ToLower() Then
            mywindow = pr.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32()
            ShowWindow(mywindow , Status)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

No argumento `Status`, se seu valor for **0**, a janela será **ocultada**, se for **1**, ela será **exibida**.

Comment: ola, seu código me parece útil, parece ser oque eu procuro, porém não compreendi como usa-lo

Comment: Insira o primeiro código na primeira linha do seu arquivo; coloque o segundo e terceiro código dentro da classe do aplicativo; chame o método `AlterarStatus()` para alterar a exibição de um processo.

Comment: Olá, o código funcionou para ocultar, porém quando troco o 0 por 1 o processo não aparece novamente, estou usando assim: http://i.imgur.com/BA51iDg.png

Comment: Tente implementar uma call externa para mostrar o processo.

Comment: estou usando 2 button diferente, como assim call externa, poderia mostrar um exemplo, porém de qualquer maneira seu código foi muito útil a mim ^^

Comment: Clique na seta para cima (ao lado da resposta) e no sinal de V para marcar essa resposta como correta, me ajuda muito ^-^

Comment: Foi muito util sua ajuda obrigado ^^, mas ainda não consegui fazer aparecer novamente  u.u