# Quais ferramentas disponíveis para criação de instaladores de projetos C#?

Tags: c#, .net, instalador

Estou com problemas para achar uma solução satisfatória de instalador para minhas aplicações Windows forms e WPF.

O que a Microsoft disponibiliza possui flexibilidade ou eu que não estou achando?

O que vocês utilizam? O que recomendam?

Comment: Um detalhe: Visual Studio é só a ferramenta que você usa para desenvolvimento. Seu projeto é em C# (ou VB, ou outra linguagem da plataforma), mas nunca em  `Visual Studio`. Qualquer dúvida, você pode ver [esta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/18246).

Comment: Tá tranquilo, vlw!

Comment: @RenanOliveira vou colocar como comentário porque não acho que seria uma resposta bem completa ou que seria uma boa resposta. O que acontece é que a Microsoft disponibiliza no Visual Studio o método do ClickOnce que cria para você o instalador... Para projetos simples ele atende perfeitamente bem, pois cria todo o instalador e tudo que é necessário.. Mas tem limitações, pois como não é uma solução completa deixa a desejar em alguns aspectos... Ai vai do que você acha que deve ter, pois o que o ClickOnce gera é muito simples e se essa simplicidade te atender, use-o, senão use o que foi citado.

Comment: @ÉrikThiago, então, já tentei ele, ele não consegue se adequar as minhas especificações necessárias....vlw ai!

Comment: Eu uso e recomendo Inno Setup. Ele é muito bom e bastante flexível. O ruim dele é que é em Pascal, mas vale à pena o esforço.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depende muito do que você quer fazer, sem maiores especificações fica difícil achar um que se encaixe no seu caso.

Existem várias soluções e cada uma delas tem uma forma diferente de trabalhar, vou me ater a listar algumas delas, sem entrar em nenhum detalhe sobre como usá-las.

- [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) - Gratuito
- [Install Shield](http://learn.flexerasoftware.com/content/IS-EVAL-InstallShield-Limited-Edition-Visual-Studio) - Tem uma versão gratuita (limitada) e uma paga (completa). O Visual Studio tem uma opção para criar um projeto "instalador" usando o Install Shield.
- [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com) - Pago
- [Wix toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/releases/) - Gratuito e open source - Não tenho muitos detalhes sobre ele, mas tenho ouvido falar muito bem, talvez deva ser a primeira opção para você avaliar.

Obviamente, também há a opção de desenvolver seu próprio instalador, específico para suas necessidades.

Comment: pode recomendar para qualquer um o Wix toolset como default, o negócio é animal, e totalmente opensource!