# Conversão de Dados

Tags: c#, sql, conversão

Estou fazendo um programa e gostaria de saber como faço para salvar um campo que contém apenas caracteres, mas mandar para o banco apenas o seu código? Eu estou usando duas tabelas para salvar os dados e o campo que eu quero salvar é a chave estrangeira que seria o código.Estou fazendo o programa no visual studio e usando o sql Developer(Oracle) como banco. Abaixo estão as duas tabelas, estou salvando na tabela Funcionario, e o cod_cargo é minha chave estrangeira. O que eu quero fazer é salvar no formulário o nome do cargo, por exemplo (Gerente), mas mandar o código desse campo para o banco. Eu fiz um insert no banco com os cargos e fiz também um carrega combo para trazer os cargos para esse campo cargo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Coloque o seu código e dê todos detalhes necessários para podermos ajudá-lo.

Comment: Jovem, não use a tag `visual-studio` se seu problema não tem relação com a IDE. [Veja essa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/18246) para entender a diferença entre IDE, linguagem de programação e compiladores. Fora isso, SQL Developer não me parece o nome de um banco de dados, posso estar enganado, mas acho que o banco que estás usando é Oracle.

Comment: Ao programar o *data binding* dos controles no formulário você pode escolher quais propriedades usar para exibição/edição e quais usar para identificação do item exibido. A solução desta pergunta passa por uma espécie de tutorial de C# WinForms/WebForms/ASP.NetMVC... ou qualquer outra ferramenta que você esteja utilizando. Acho que o ideal para você é procurar por tutorial da ferramenta que você esteja utilizando para aprender os conceitos e recursos básicos, e depois fazer perguntas mais específicas.

Comment: Você que mostrar m um formulário no nome do cargo, mas que salvar na tabela Funcionario o Cod_Cargo, se for isso, não vejo problema esta mais que correto, o que precisar fazer é um JOIN com suas tabelas para carregar em seu formulário o NOME do CARGO e não o Código.