# Abrir arquivos, passando variável como nome do arquivo

Tags: c++, arquivo

Tenho a seguinte situação, um arquivo "tabelas.txt" onde tenho em torno de 2000 linhas com nome de arquivos a qual quero passar linha a linha pegando o nome dos arquivos e verificar quais existem e quais não.

O problema ocorre quando após pegar o nome do arquivo a ser verificado tento passar ele para abri-lo depois `ifstream obj (arq)`, o estranho é que se eu digitar passando a *string* com o caminho e não a variável `arq` que é *string* o arquivo é lido sem problemas.

Segue o código utilizado:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main () {
    string line;    
    ifstream myfile ("tabelas.txt"); 
    if (myfile.is_open()){
        while (! myfile.eof() ) 
        {
            getline (myfile,line); 
            string arq = "..\\dados\\"+ line+".csv";

            ifstream obj (arq);
            if (!obj) 
                cerr<<"Ocorreu um erro ao abrir o arquivo"<<endl;
        }
    myfile.close();
    }

    else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

    return 0;
}
```

Segue imagem demonstrando o erro:

http://prntscr.com/by4opb

Comment: Não consegui reproduzir o erro http://ideone.com/VCbQyo

Comment: estais utilizando qual IDE? estou utilizando o Dev-C++

Comment: Não usei IDE algum, isso não importa. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101

Comment: Compreendo a diferença entre os termos, porem já vi acontecer erro no dev c o qual não acontecia no Code::Blocks, acabou sendo mais por curiosidade mesmo. Tentei de diversas formas e não foi possível, acabei fazendo em python porem, se possível gostaria de saber como fazer em C++ também, tens alguma outra forma(ex: outra função) que eu possa obter o resultado a qual procuro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reconstruí ele para ler arquivos da forma como normalmente faço.

Segue o código abaixo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    ifstream myfile ("x.txt", ifstream::in);
    string line;
    if(myfile.is_open()){
        while(getline(myfile, line)){
            line = "..\\dados\\" + line + ".csv";
            ifstream testfile (line.c_str(), ifstream::in);
            if(testfile.is_open()){
                cout << "O arquivo '"<< line <<"' existe\n";
            }else{
                cout << "O arquivo '" << line << "' nao existe\n";
            }
        }
    }
    myfile.close();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Desculpa, não compreendi o que quisesse dizer com os caracteres estarem codificados.

Comment: Eita, Agora estava funcionando .-.

Comment: Opa!!! Vi somente agora que editou hahah. Seu código funcionou perfeitamente e observei que o diferente entre nossos código era o ".c_str()", somente adicionando isso funcionou, alem disso o meu código apresentou uma performasse maior. Onde seu demorou alguns segundos para demonstrar os arquivos que não existiam enquanto o meu foi "instantâneo". Agradeço muito pela sua ajuda. E vou dar um mix entre os códigos trazendo a melhor parte de cada, pois o seu visivelmente ficou muito melhor que o meu.

Comment: retificando: ambos foram "instantâneos" , eu estava rodando uns processos pesados na maquina no momento que executei o seu !!