# Como saber se o cliente me enviou algo?

Tags: c#, .net, socket, assincronismo

Fiz esse código aqui seguindo alguns tutoriais pela internet.

```
buttonAbrirConexão.Enabled = false;
TcpListener servidor = new TcpListener(6554);
servidor.Start();
while(true)
{
    Thread.Sleep(2500);
    if(servidor.Pending())
    {
    MessageBox.Show("Cliente conectado");
    Socket conexão = servidor.AcceptSocket();
    socketStream = new NetworkStream(conexão);
    escrever = new BinaryWriter(socketStream);
    ler = new BinaryReader(socketStream);
    escrever.Write("Alguma coisa");
    break;
    }
}
```

Antes de usar o `ler.Read(),` como vou saber se o cliente antes me mandou algo? Como saber também oque ele mandou? `String`? `int`?

Será que existir uma forma de disparar um evento assíncrono sempre que um cliente tentar conexão?

Comment: Você precisar dar uma lida nisso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sem entrar no mérito desse código estar adequado, até porque imagino que seja apenas uma tentativa inicial o problema é usar o `Pending()`. Se retirá-lo o "servidor" ficará esperando receber alguma coisa.

Agora se quer fazer assíncrono, a principal mudança seria pegar o método assíncrono [`AcceptSocketAsync()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.acceptsocketasync?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Net_Sockets_TcpListener_AcceptSocketAsync), algo assim:

```
buttonAbrirConexão.Enabled = false;
TcpListener servidor = new TcpListener(6554);
servidor.Start();
while(true) {
    MessageBox.Show("Cliente conectado");
    Socket conexão = await servidor.AcceptSocketAsync();
    socketStream = new NetworkStream(conexão);
    escrever = new BinaryWriter(socketStream);
    ler = new BinaryReader(socketStream);
    escrever.Write("Alguma coisa");
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/Socket.cs).

[Veja um exemplo](https://bsmadhu.wordpress.com/2012/09/29/simplify-asynchronous-programming-with-c-5-asyncawait/).

Não tem como saber pleo código o que está vindo. Esse mecanismo transmite *bytes*, não dados específicos. Apenas um protocolo previamente combinado poderá determinar o que são os dados. O tipo do ser fixo, pode depender de posição, pode até ter metadados informando quais são os tipos dos dados.

Comment: Não entendi esse loop sem verificações que você colocou ai, seguindo isso ele vai ficar só colocando a mensagem "Cliente conectado" o tempo todo, não?

Comment: O exemplo é realmente espetacular, eu não sabia dessa instrução await

Comment: Vai toda vez que tiver uma conexão, antes o que ele fazia é pegar um dado e encerrar o servidor, normalmente não é o que deseja. Claro que precisa ter uma forma de sair, por isso falei que esse código está ruim e indiquei um exemplo melhor.

Comment: Consegui fazer o servidor rodar entre dois computadores, valeu!!! Agora já tenho outra dúvida e vou tirar no fórum