# Xamarin tem alguma limitação para criação de APP para Android

Tags: android, mobile, xamarin

Estou começando a estudar programação mobile, especificamente Android no momento, e estou com uma dúvida.

Comecei a estudar o **Android Studio** que usa a linguagem JAVA, mas é possível desenvolver também para Android utilizando o Visual Studio com **Xamarin** e a linguagem C# (IDE e linguagem que já tenho uma experiencia boa).

Aplicação criada com Xamarin tem alguma limitação técnica? Alguma limitação de versão de Android ou algo que seja diferente de um app criado com Android Studio?

Obrigado a todos.

Comment: Deve usar o Xamarin, claro. De qualquer forma não dá para comparar as duas coisas, afinal Xamarin é uma tecnologia, Android Studo é um IDE. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101 Se a pergunta for reformulada não pedindo opiniões ou comparações amplas e de coisas não comparáveis, dá para reabrir.

Comment: Obrigado pelo feedback, alterei a pergunta, espero que tenha ficado adequada. E obrigado também pela resposta.

Comment: Não, continua pedindo uma opinião. Respostas puramente opinativas não são permitidas já que elas não ajudam ninguém de fato. Eu dei minha opinião como comentário. Se você acha que deve tomar uma decisão de vida baseado no que uma pessoa aleatória na internet que não te conhece disse, aí é algo que só você pode decidir se é bom. Mas o sistema não foi criado para suportar respostas oficiais sobre isso.

Comment: Não estou tomando decisão de vida baseado em alguém aleatório da internet. Estou procurando pessoas que estão na área e saibam sobre o assunto (que pra mim é totalmente novo) e que me mostram alguns pontos sobre as tecnologias em questão para então eu ter o que pesquisar a respeito e tirar minha conclusão. Mas entendo completamente que se esta não é o sistema correto para fazer isso meu post deve ser removido. Peço desculpas por ter postado minha questão na plataforma sem ter lido atentamente os termos.

Comment: Por isso que perguntas baseadas em opiniões não são permitidas aqui. A pessoas acham exatamente o que você acha, que as opiniões postadas aqui vão ajudar, mas elas não vão. As pessoas experientes sabem disto. As iniciantes ainda não perceberam como isso não ajuda. Perguntas mais objetivas ou que tenha um pequeno grau de subjetividade podem ser feitas, essa não pode ser respondida, pelo menos na forma atual. Ainda é possível reformular para salvá-la. Pode ler a [help] para ver se te ajuda. Ou ainda: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/486/101 ou http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/488/101

Comment: Entendi completamente a questão. Dei uma modificada na pergunta, veja se ela esta adequada agora. Obrigado pelo toque.

Comment: Reabri, vamos ver o que a comunidade acha e se podem responder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua pergunta é muito importante para entendimento do Xamarin.

Muitos acreditam que a plataforma Xamarin não seja nativa, ai que eles se enganam, pois Xamarin é nativo, sendo possível realizar absolutamente tudo que você faria em Android Studio.

Exemplo: Se uma API especifica, como por exemplo, câmera, possuir um problema, esse mesmo problema reproduzido no Android Studio(Java) será reproduzido no Xamarin(C# ou F#), pois ambos utilizam o NDK para acessar as api's nativas.

Lembrando que será necessária uma curva de aprendizagem para desenvolver aplicações Mobile, porém, uma vez já familiarizado com a linguagem, tende a ser menor essa curva.

Espero ter exclarecido sua dúvida.

Comment: Legal, muito obrigado pela resposta. Era isso que queria saber, se tem diferença utilizando um ou outro, mas pelo visto não. 
Estou entrando de férias mês que vem da faculdade e começarei a estudar xamarin.