# Preencher gráfico com dados do mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em C# e preciso preencher um gráfico com a quantidade de dados cadastrados em 3 tabelas do MySql.
Fica da seguinte forma: O gráfico deve informar ao usuário em colunas diferentes quantos dados estão cadastrados nas tabelas produtos, logsentrada e logssaida respectivamente, como na imagem abaixo:

[image: tabela de dados]

Tenho a dificuldade de tornar isso possível.
Segue imagem com o gráfico no formulário:

[image: gráfico no formulário]

String de conexão:

```
public class DadosDaConexao
{
    public static String servidor = "%";
    public static String banco = "estoque_box";
    public static String usuario = "estBox";
    public static String senha = "estoqueBox";
    public static String StringDeConexao
    {
        get
        {
            return "Server=" + servidor + ";Database=" + banco + ";Uid=" + usuario + ";Pwd=" + senha;
        }
    }
}
```

Acho que isso pode ajudar:

```
public void loadChart()
    {
        MySqlConnection conexao = new MySqlConnection();
        conexao.ConnectionString = DadosDaConexao.StringDeConexao;
        conexao.Open();
        string Query = "select count(*) from produto where pro_cod;";
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conexao);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;
        try
        {
            myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                this.GrProdutos.Series["Produto"].Points.AddXY(myReader.GetString("pro_cod"), myReader.GetString("pro_cod"));
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        conexao.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Algumas dicas: 1. não use a tag `visual-studio` se o problema não tiver relação com a IDE. Se tiver alguma dúvida, recomendo a leitura de: [O que é linguagem de programação, IDE e compilador?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/18246); 2. Nos mostre o que você já tentou, de preferência adicione um [mcve]; 3. Tente explicar a dificuldade que está tendo, da forma atual a pergunta é muito ampla e possivelmente será fechada por isso.

Comment: Eu já adicionei ao gráfico, porém função nenhuma foi adicionada à ele

Comment: Quando você executa a consulta no banco, o que o seu método está retornando um DataTable ? Coloca ai na pergunta como você esta fazendo a consulta.

Comment: Adicionei o código @Robss70

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu erro está no SQL

```
select count(*) from produto where pro_cod;
```

Esta faltando o parametro do cod ex:

```
select count(*) from produto where pro_cod = 1 group by parametrodeAgrupamento;
```

outra coisa se você quer usar a coluna `pro_cod` ela deve vir no select,

```
select count(*) as count, pro_cod from produto where pro_cod = 1 group by parametrodeAgrupamento;
```

Sobre a orientação do Grafico você esta adicionando valores iguais no x e no y

Isso não vai dar muito certo, precisa rever o que necessária-mente você quer exibir no gráfico
Dica não vá pela tentativa e erro, intenda oque está a fazer para depois fazer.

utilize desta maneira

```
myReader.GetString("count")
```