# Como unir duas listas diferentes usando LINQ e where?

Tags: c#, linq

Tenho três classes:

```
class Cid
{
        public string cid  { get; set; } //importo esse campo via txt
        public string descricao { get; set; } //importo esse campo via txt
}

class Relacionamento
{
        public string cid { get; set; } //importo esse campo via txt
        public string codigo { get; set; } //importo esse campo via txt
        public string procedimento { get; set; } //PRECISO DESSE CAMPO
}

class Procedimento
{
        public string codigo { get; set; } //importo esse campo via txt
        public string procedimento { get; set; } //importo esse campo via txt
}
```

Criei uma lista para as classes: `listaCid` para a `classe Cid`, e `listaProcedimento` para a `classe Procedimento`

Depois das classes criadas, o usuário clica em um item da `listaCid`.

Após clicar, a `listaRelacionamento` é filtrada usando where `Cid.cid = Relacionamento.Cid`. Até aqui tudo bem.

Quero saber como faço pra incluir na `listaRelacionamento` (após o filtro), o campo `Relacionamento.procedimento` vindo da `listaProcedimento`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pela imagem, vocês podem ver: O usuário clica no grid de cima que recebe a listaCid (nesse caso, recebeu o código A013) e passa pro grid de baixo listaRelacionamento (vejam que filtra todos os campos onde cid = A013), mas a terceira coluna fica vazia.

Quero preencher a terceira coluna do listaRelacionamento pelo campo pintado de azul (procedimento)

Comment: Tente colocar também o procedimento que você diz que está fazendo. Tá muito confuso o que você pretende fazer. Aliás, não use a tag `visual-studio` se o problema não tiver relação com a IDE. Dica de leitura: [O que é linguagem de programação, IDE e compilador?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/18246)

Comment: vou alterar a pergunta

Comment: Todas essas classes são coleções? Vem da onde essas coleções?

Comment: não sei se são coleções. criei as classes como mostrei no código, na mão mesmo. e importo os dados de um arquivo txt.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem a classe `Relacionamento`, qual é a finalidade do campo `codigo` e `procedimento` desta classe?

Comment: Não seria mais facil apenas criar os campos `codcid` e `codprocedimento` na classe `Relacionamento`? Mas de qualquer forma, esta confusa sua pergunta, sugiro q seja mais especifico e facilite para gente aqui.

Comment: a finalidade da tabela relacionamento é unir as tabelas cid e procedimento

Comment: a questão é que os arquivos txt com essas informações já vem prontos. poderia até ser mais fácil fazer do jeito que você falou acima, mas de todo jeito eu teria que unir os arquivos pra poder criar os novos campos na classe Relacionamento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Penso que se percebi bem a tua pergunta o que queres é isto:

```
 List<Relacionamento> result = (from relacionamento in ListaRelacionamentos
                    join procedimento in ListaProcedimento
                         on relacionamento.codigo equals procedimento.codigo
                    select new Relacionamento()
                    {
                     cid =   relacionamento.cid,
                      codigo =  relacionamento.codigo,
                       procedimento = procedimento.procedimento
                    }).ToList();
```

Mas recomendo usares entity framework e objectos ... por ex: da só terias que navegar dentro do objecto ao fazeres o filtro.

```
 class Relacionamento
 {
     public string cid { get; set; } //importo esse campo via txt
    public Procedimentos procedimento { get; set; } //importo esse campo via txt
}
```

Comment: você pode me dar um exemplo de entity framework e objetos que você falou? acho que vai resolver, mas ainda não sei implementar

Comment: sua primeira dica funcionou ^^ mas se puder explicar melhor a segunda dica (botar uma classe dentro da outra), eu acho bom pra aprender ^^. abraço.

Comment: acho que isto já é um pouco complexo para estar a explicar assim. mas em resumo, qualquer objecto pode conter multiplos objectos, tal qual meti no segundo exemplo.. Estando os mesmos disponiveis para leitura atraves do objecto pai. 

Investiga um pouco sobre Entity framework, para projectos simples.. basicamente instalas o entity e importas/crias o modelo de dados para o projecto..a partir desse momento poderias fazer por ex: 

Relationamento rel = new Relacionamento(); .. e depois para aceder ao procedimento.. rel.Procedimento.nome;

Comment: mas tal como disse, isto assim pode ser muito confuso.. exprimenta fazer um tutorial ou isso..

Comment: ok, de qualquer forma, sua dica me ajudou a solucionar meu problema. abraço.