# Exportar Dados para FireBase

Tags: c#, json, firebase

Gostaria de exportar dados para meu BD **FireBase**.

Tenho um serviço criado no *Visual Studio* em **C#** que cria uma lista com nome e preço. Preciso exportar esses dados para o FireBase ou exportar um arquivo txt, caso precise já faz isso.

Observação: o dados já estão no formato **JSON**.

Aqui eu chamo meu método para converter o formato para JSON:

```
Library.ConverterJSON(listaAlterada);
```

Nesta outra parte encontra-se o método no qual eu converto os dados:

```
public static void ConverterJSON(List<Tabela> listaAlterada)
    {
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listaAlterada);
        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\hmogu\OneDrive\Documentos\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TestWindowsService\TestWindowsService\bin\Debug\JSON.txt", json);
    }
```

Neste método eu imprimo os dados em um arquivo txt.

A dúvida é a seguinte:
Eu gostaria de pegar esses dados impressos no bloco txt da minha máquina e exporta-los/envia-los para meu banco de dados FireBase.

Comment: E qual é a dúvida? Aliás, em Lisboa já é tarde. Não tem porquê dizer bom dia ***=)***. Ah, importante também, não use a tag `visual-studio` se sua dúvida não tiver relação com a IDE, se tiver alguma dúvida em relação a isso, pode ler [essa pergunta sobre IDE, linguagem de programação e compilador](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/18246).

Comment: Nao trablaho com C# mas se os dados ja estao em json é só dar um set no banco, algo assim(versao web) `firebase.database.ref().set(seuObjetoJson)`. Problema aqui é que vai apagar tudo que ja tem no banco, sobrescrever desde a raiz. Mas isso é facilmente resolvivel. Se espeificar um pouco melhor o uqe precisa fica mais facil, ate por que isso ja esta na [documentacao do firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/)

Comment: @jbueno, tem porque dizer sim uma saudação pois é questão de educação, independente se não é compatível com seu fuso, é só responder de acordo com o mesmo. Obrigado pela dica sobre usar as tags e por não ter precisão em usar uma vez que sei o que é IDE. Minha dúvida como está explicitada no tópico é a seguinte: eu preciso exportar um array com dados para popular meu banco no FireBase, os dados já estão no formato JSON.

`Library.ConverterJSON(listaAlterada);`

Comment: Meu método:

`public static void ConverterJSON(List<Tabela> listaAlterada)
        {
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listaAlterada);
            File.WriteAllText(@"meuCaminho", json);
        }`

Comment: @NeuberOliveira, estou com dificuldade em como pegarei meu dados e comunicarei com o FireBase..

Comment: Ficou um pouco mais claro @jbueno.. as vezes eu não consegui explicar direito ainda.. =/

Comment: @HenriqueGusmão Entendo, porém é algo desencorajado pelo site, uma vez que queremos dar o total de atenção pra dúvida sobre programação, então saudações e agradecimentos seriam algo meio que "desnecessários". Se você quiser, pode ler mais sobre isso [nesta publicação sobre saudações e agradecimentos no meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/846/18246). Claro que isso não é regra, só estou tentando te dar uma dica, você aceita se quiser. Sobre a pergunta: ainda acho que ela não está bem clara, você pode clicar [edit], colocar seu código e tentar explicar melhor o problema.

Comment: @jbueno, farei isso então! muito obrigado.. vou editar e ficarei muito grato se puder me ajudar!!

Comment: voce consegue fazer um insert/set de qualquer coisa no firebase via codigo? por que me parece que a questão é exatamente essa.

Comment: A intenção é justamente ajudar. Diretamente, ou  ajudar a melhorar a pergunta pra que alguém possa responder.

Comment: @NeuberOliveira eu não sei como usar o insert/set no FireBase. Eu editei minha pergunta, ficou mais claro?!

Comment: @jbueno, editei, melhorou?

Comment: Como disse unca mexi com C#, o firebase nao tem nenhuma biblioteca oficial para C# mas você consegue fazer o basico do banco via [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/?hl=pt-br) ou procura por algum SDK de C# de terceiro. Boa sorte.

Comment: valeu @NeuberOliveira!!

Comment: Se você já tem o ficheiro JSON, você pode importar para a Consola do Firebase.