# Programa em C "comendo" caracteres quando executado

Tags: c, string, printf

Seguinte,
Todas as IDEs que programo em C estão dando saida com caracteres a menos a cada iteração. Por exemplo, ao executar um for, a cada iteração um ou mais caracteres somem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observem que tanto no netbeans quanto no DevC++ ele ocorre o mesmo erro.
Creio ser algo relacionado ao compilador, já que outras linguagens como Java por exemplo, não apresentam esse problema nesse ambiente.

Não consegui encontrar nada relacionado, portanto não tenho links de referências.
Segue Codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int alunos[10];
    int i, idade;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("insira a idade do aluno %d" + (i + 1));
        scanf("%d", &idade);
        alunos[i] = idade;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d \n", alunos[i]);
    }
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Esquece esse negócio de IDE. Leia isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mude esta linha:

```
printf("insira a idade do aluno %d", i + 1);
```

Você não pode concatenar tudo como estava fazendo. Curiosamente você sabe fazer o certo e coloca um *placeholder* para encaixar o valor que precisa. Não esqueça de usar a vírgula, já que o valor a ser usado é um outro parâmetro da função [`printf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), não é para "somar" com a *string*. Leia a documentação com atenção.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
    int alunos[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("insira a idade do aluno %d", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &alunos[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) printf("%d\n", alunos[i]);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/69V83d). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/znpiatqs-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Console/PrintfProblem.c).

Comment: Realmente percebi que esse erro estava bem recorrente assim que li a resposta, acho que é a por que no Java é assim então acabei por fazer igual, o erro foi resolvido, obrigado.

Comment: Alternar entre linguagens é um problema. Tem vezes que fico meia hora tentando entender o erro em usar "->" no java ou "." no PHP....

Answer (score 7):

Altere a linha

> `printf("insira a idade do aluno %d" + (i + 1));`

para

```
printf("insira a idade do aluno %d" ,i+1);
```

Answer (score 5):

O pessoal já identificou o erro e colocou a forma certa - mas eu acho que vale a pena explicar o que estava acontecendo:

Ao colocar a linha:

```
printf("insira a idade do aluno %d" + (i + 1));
```

O resultado da expressão entre é o que era passado ao "printf" - bom, C não tem um "tipo string" propriamente dito - todas as strings, que por convenção apontam para uma cadeia de valores do tipo char - e as chamadas da stlib convencionam que ao se encontrar um valor "0" se chegou ao final da string.

Por isso, quando declaramos strings que serão alteradas durante a execução, são do tipo "char *" - e strings fixas, embora escritas como vários caractéres entre `"` internamente são a mesma coisa: o compilador cria aquela cadeia de caracteres em um ponto na memória do programa, e o código todo usa um ponteiro para aquele ponto na memória.

Ao escrever `"insira ..." + (i + 1)`, o compilador somou o número (i + 1) ao ponteiro para a string estática - então o printf nesse caso, recebe em cada passada do  `for i` um valor um byte mais pra frente como sendo o endereço do início da string. Como na codificação de texto que o programa usa, um equivale a um caractére , temos os caracteres sendo progressivamente "comidos", em cada interação.

Tem coisas que só o C faz por você.  Nas outras linguagens, chamadas de "mais alto nível" pra que tem uma abstração maior, as strings são reais, e tentar somar o número a string teria um de três efeitos, dependendo da linguagem: (1) Erro de sintaxe, por que o operador `+` não é permitido para strings, (2) Erro de tipagem, por que não se está definida a operação de "+" entre strings e inteiros ou (3) uma conversão implícita do número para string e concatenação do resultado - mas mesmo assim, o número seria colocado ao final da string, não substituindo o "%d" na string.

(A título de curiosidade, na linguagem Python a substituição de marcações do tipo %s e %d por valores está definida entre strings e outros objetos com o operador `%` - e isso aqui funcionaria: `print("insira a idade do aluno %d:" % (i + 1))` )