# Utilizando o CellClick para carregar dados de um registro

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Estou fazendo uma aplicação em C# no Windows Forms do Visual Studio sem usar banco de dados, estou controlando tudo por uma classe (Pessoa) e mais duas classes (PessoaFisica e PessoaJuridica) herdadas da classe base.

Estou tentando carregar o `DataGrid` com os dados de um cadastro que eu faço no programa no momento que eu clico na linha selecionada, mas não estou conseguindo (o que inicialmente precisa aparecer nas linhas do `DataGrid` é o primeiro dado cadastrado e depois quando selecionar ela com um clique aí sim aparece todos os dados de volta nas `TextBox` onde eles foram inseridas). Por exemplo, eu mostro o nome de cada usuario cadastrado nas linhas da datagrid e quando eu clico em uma linha, quero que os dados cadastrados sejam mostrados de volta em cada textbox onde ele foi inserido.

Estou salvando os dados do cadastro em uma lista, desta forma

```
List<Pessoa> listcadastro = new List<Pessoa>();
listcadastro.Add(new Pessoa(/*aqui eu coloco cada text box que contem os dados que eu quero*/));
```

mas não estou conseguindo entender como fazer isso e também vi que pode ser usado o `CellClick`. Não estou postando o código pois não esta ocorrendo nenhum erro pois eu não estou sabendo como implementar o codigo essa função RowSelectionChanged para exibir os dados cadastrados pela textbox no momento que eu clico na linha selecionada.

Vi que tem sobre o event data aqui nesse site: [RowSelectionChanged Event (WebHierarchicalDataGrid)](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/ASPNET/2016.1/CLR4.0/html/Infragistics4.Web.v16.1~Infragistics.Web.UI.GridControls.WebHierarchicalDataGrid~RowSelectionChanged_EV.html) dizendo que existe o CurrentSelectedRows e PreviousSelectedRows e gostaria de saber se um desses realmente atende o que eu preciso.

**Atualização:**

Está dando erro na parte de salvar, é nessa parte de pegar o index

```
List<Pessoa> listcadastro = new List<Pessoa>();

//exibir todos os nomes que foram cadastrados um em baixo do outro na grid
       int Row;
private void bt_salvar_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    listcadastro.Add(new Pessoa(txt_nome.Text, txt_endereco.Text, int.Parse(txt_ano.Text), txt_telefone.Text));
    Row = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(listcadastro[Row].Nome);
}

//mostrar todos os dados de volta na textbox em que foi inserido quando selecionar a linha 
public void DataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.RowCount > 0)
    {
        txt_nome.Text = dataGridView1[0, dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();
        txt_endereco.Text = dataGridView1[0, dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();
        txt_ano.Text = dataGridView1[0, dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();
        txt_telefone.Text = dataGridView1[0, dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();

    }
}
```

Aqui em baixo eu fiz uma montagem mostrando como é para ficar, ali na grid aparece só o nome do usuario cadastrado 
 [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor, seja mais específico. Não temos como saber qual problema você está tendo se não colocar o código que está usando, dizer qual o resultado esperado e qual resultado está sendo produzido até o momento. E também, não use a tag `visual-studio` se o seu problema não for relacionado diretamente com a IDE. É possível ver mais detalhes sobre IDE, compiladores e linguagens de programação [nesta pergunta aqui do Stack Overflow em Português](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/18246).

Comment: O erro no salvar pode ser causado pelo `dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index`, uma vez que não necessariamente terá uma linha selecionada quando o usuário clicar no botão de salvar. A pergunta tá bem confusa. Achei que o problema era sobre como resgatar a `Pessoa` selecionada, mas parece que agora é como salvar na lista. Qual é a dúvida?

Comment: É que eu acabei atualizando a pergunta. Mas no caso a pessoa selecionada também era uma dúvida e você respondeu (muito bem, ótima solução) mas também preciso saber como pegar a index que está representada por x aqui -> dataGridView1.Rows.Add(listcadastro[x].nome) (os dados cadastrais já estão sendo salvos numa array list que eu coloquei ali no código). Resumindo, na datagrid eu só quero mostrar o nome de cada usuário cadastrado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para identificar a `Pessoa` selecionada você pode recuperar direto da sua lista através do index da linha selecionada:

```
private void DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Pessoa pessoaSelecionada = listcadastro[datagridview1.CurrentCell.RowIndex];
    txt_nome.Text = pessoaSelecionada.Nome;
    txt_endereco.Text = pessoaSelecionada.Endereco;
    txt_ano.Text = pessoaSelecionada.Ano.ToString();
    txt_telefone.Text = pessoaSelecionada.Telefone;
}
```

---

Para adicionar no grid da forma que está implementando, você pode fazer:

```
listcadastro.Add(new Pessoa(txt_nome.Text, txt_endereco.Text, int.Parse(txt_ano.Text), txt_telefone.Text));
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(listcadastro.Last().Nome);
```

Comment: E para exibir só o nome do usuario cadastrado na lista da grid, como eu faço para pegar o index x(não finito) que aparece aqui -> dataGridView1.Rows.Add(listcadastro[x].nome) ?

Comment: Cara, me desculpe, mas ainda não entendi. Você quer adicionar a lista inteira no grid ou você quer adicionar uma pessoa recém criada?

Comment: Eu adicionei todos os dados na array list já, mas quero mostrar na grid só o primeiro dado informado (que foi o nome). E aquilo que você me respondeu eu vou usar para mostrar o resto dos dados de volta nas textbox na linha que foi selecionada (no nome que foi selecionado).

Comment: Entendi. E o Rows.Add()? Você quer adicionar o que?

Comment: Quero só adicionar a informação do nome na grid, daí tentei acessar pelo index mas o x está indefinido e não sei como indicar que ali no x é o index da linha selecionada

Comment: Editei a resposta. Veja se é isso que quer, por favor

Comment: É que na grid eu só quero exibir um dos dados que eu digitei, aquele da text box nome, só ele vai aparecer na grid. E daí quando eu clicar na linha com o mouse, aí sim as outras informações vão aparecer nas textbox mostrando os dados cadastrais.

Comment: E não é isso que o código que postei faz? hehe

Comment: Mas dá erro a partir do new Pessoa(); e dá para fazer o que eu quero só usando dataGridView1.Rows.Add(clients[x].name) mas eu não sei como definir o x que é o index da linha

Comment: Editei novamente. Veja se é isso, por favor

Comment: Sim! Muito obrigado cara, vlw mesmo! Aprendi muito com você, obrigado mesmo!

Answer (score 1):

```
if (dgv_pessoa.RowCount > 0)
        {
            TuaTextBox.Text =  dgv_pessoa[0, dgv_pessoa.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();                 
        }
```

o zero (0) é o índice da culuna.

**coloque no evento CellClick ou CellDoubleClick.**

Comment: por exemplo, ali no caso do dgv_pessoa[0... eu vou precisar usar os outros, daí como eu faço? atualizei a pergunta com a parte do código com o botão para salvar e a do CellClick

Answer (score 0):

Eu acho que ficaria bom assim.
Explicando: Como você adicionou um objeto à grid, você na hora que for chamar a linha pode dar um cast convertendo ela para esse objeto e chamar a propriedade que você quer.

```
private void DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textbox1.Text = ((Pessoa)DataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem).endereco;
}
```