# Compilação padrao para linux

Tags: linux

blz galera, eo seguinte se eu compilo um arquivo em .exe eu posso leva-lo para uma maquina recem formatada com windows sem nada instalado e rodar este arquivo, queria saber como fazer isso para linux, não me interessa se compilei de um script C,PYTHON,RUBY emfim quero rodar em qualquer maquina.

Comment: Seja bem-vindo ao Stackoverflow. Creio que sua pergunta não está no escopo do site. Peço-lhe a gentileza de clicar no botão [editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/195675/edit) para poder adicionar informações, de maneira a deixar sua pergunta mais clara,

Answer (score 1):

Python e Ruby não são compilados, ou seja não geram arquivos executáveis, eles são interpretados pelos programas da linguagem, com exceção do C.

- Desde que você tenha o programa Ruby instalado na máquina o script `.rb` irão funcionar.
- Python esta presente em várias distros Linux, mas claro que ele não vai virar um executável, ainda dependerá de alguma coisa para dar o "arranque", talvez um outro executável ou um `.sh`

Creio que a linguagem C seria o que você poderá compilar em qualquer ambiente, desde que use as libs e APIs que sejam compatíveis entre diferentes sistemas, no entanto creio que você não entenda o que é um programa compilado e talvez por isto desta confusão, **recomendo** que antes de tudo e antes de ler o resto da minha resposta leia isto com muita atenção:

- [O que é linguagem de programação, IDE e compilador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/3635)

Se terminou de ler todas resposta então vou lhe dar sugestões, primeiro existem linguagens que garantem criar aplicações cross-platform, mas isto no geral sempre depende de algo, por exemplo muitos dizem que [java](/questions/tagged/java) é cross-platform, mas na verdade para rodar um programa escrito java em um computador é necessário https://www.java.com/pt_BR/download/help/index_installing.xml, no entanto existem programas que podem criar um "exe" (claro que no caso é somente para Windows) como o: http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net (ultima atualização em 2007).

Mas como eu disse ainda sim para outros sistemas como Mac OSX e as várias distros diferentes e geralmente "não portáveis" de Linux terá que instalar o Java de fato.

Python como citei geralmente veem com os linux voltados para usuários domésticos por padrão, em outros casos somente instalando, no Windows também será necessário instalar e então os scripts `.py` poderão ser iniciados, claro que tem a parte do "arranque", por exemplo tem um game chamado [Frets On Fire](http://fretsonfire.sourceforge.net) que foi escrito em Python (provavelmente usando [Pygame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pygame)), ele é suportado para Windows, Mac OSX e Linux, mas claro que ainda existem dependencias, eu não sei como Pygame funciona, mas o processo de *deploy* para Windows provavelmente envia um versão do Python acompanhado já e tem um `.exe` (ou gera), o mesmo não ocorre outros sistemas diferentes talvez seja necessário instalar na maquina por si mesmo.

Como disse [c](/questions/tagged/c) talvez seria o ideal, mas é uma linguagem que talvez não leve muito tempo para você construir uma aplicação da maneira que quer, então poderia experimentar o [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), mas não o ele sozinho, mas sim com um framework (acho que é assim que se chama) como o [Qt](https://www.qt.io), o Qt tem libs compatíveis entre diferentes sistemas, ou seja um C++ escrito com as libs do Qt pode ser compilado em qualquer sistema que você tenha instalado o Qt, como:

> Windows, Linux/X11, Mac OSX, Embedded Linux, QNX, QNX 6.6.0 (armv7le e x86), Android, iOS, WinRT e Windows Phone 8.1.

Note que o Qt Community (o "gratuito") não suporta tudo, mas suporta muitas distros linux, Mac OSX e Windows, claro que para compilar em cada sistema terá que baixar o SDK em cada sistema e ter cada um dos sistemas:

- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html
- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html
- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/osx.html#deploying-applications-on-macos

Ou seja, com o Qt você pode conseguir o resultado desejado, mas claro que dependerá de muito estudo e pratica, não vai ser só chegar e arrastar no programa QtDesigner, ou só porque estudou um pouco de [c](/questions/tagged/c) que vai chegar entendendo as libs do Qt.