# Como deixar armazenado os valores do vetor?

Tags: c, array, algoritmo

Sou iniciante em C e estou á 2 dias nesse exercício, consegui fazê-lo de forma que se você aumentar o vetor com a função `realloc`, ele vai aumentar tudo certo, mas preciso que ele guarde os valores que você digitou.

Por exemplo, quero um vetor de 2 posições, e depois vou realocá-lo com + 3 posições, ele não deveria pedir pra inserir todo os valores do vetor novamente mas sim habilitar para inserir valores APENAS para estas 3 novas posições.

Como fazer para que ele guarde o que já foi armazenado em um primeiro momento no vetor?

*Não* consegui deixar armazenado os valores que o usuário digita na primeira vez quando o vetor é alocado ***e depois só preencher realocando os valores das NOVAS POSICOES***, ou seja, deixar o usuário preencher novos valores só nesses novas posicoes e MANTER OS NUMEROS DIGITADOS ANTERIORMENTE

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int main(void)
{
    int *p;
    int i,k,n;
    printf ("\nDigite a quantidade de numeros que serao digitados: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf ("%d",&i); // a variavel i vai receber a quantidade de numeros que sera necessario para o vetor

    /* a função malloc reserva espaço suficiente para um vetor de inteiros.
    caso sejam digitados 5 elementos serão reservados 20 bytes, pois cada
    inteiro ocupa 4 bytes na memória */

    p=(int*)malloc(i*sizeof(int)); // Aloca um espaço de memoria para um vetor de inteiros
    if (p==NULL) // verifica se ha memoria disponivel ANTES de habilitar para preencher vetor
    {
        printf ("\nERRO.MEMORIA INSUFICIENTE");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (k=0;k<i;k++) // preenche o vetor
    {
        printf ("\nDigite o %d numero do vetor: ",k+1);
        fflush(stdin); //limpar buffer do teclado
        scanf ("%d",&p[k]);
    }
    printf ("\n\n\t\t========== VETOR PREENCHIDO ==========\n");
    for (k=0;k<i;k++) // Mostra vetor preenchido
    {
        printf ("\t\t%d",p[k]);
    }

      printf ("\n\nSeu vetor possui %d elementos.",i);
      printf ("\nDigite um valor positivo para aumentar ao vetor.");
      printf ("\n\n");
      fflush(stdin);
      scanf ("%d",&n); // n vai receber a quantidade de posicoes que tera de ser realocado o vetor para inserção de novos numeros

      if ((i+n)<0) // Testa para ver se o usuario vai digitar um valor positivo para aumentar o vetor dinamicamente
      {
          printf ("\nSeu vetor possui quantidade negativa de elemento.\n\nIMPOSSIVEL ALOCAR MEMORIA.\n\n");
          free(p);
          return 0;
          system("pause");
      }

      /* a função realloc aumenta (numero positivo) ou diminui (numero negativo), o tamanho do
      vetor dinamicamente. ela recebe o ponteiro para o vetor anterior e retorna o novo espaço alocado */

      p=(int*)(realloc(p,(i+n)*sizeof(int))); // REaloca um espaço de memoria para a quantidade informada
      if (p==NULL) //Testa novamente mas agora para saber se ha espaço disponivel para a REalocacao
      {
          printf ("\nERRO DE REALOCACAO.MEMORIA INSUFICIENTE");
          exit(1);
      }
      for (k=0;k<(n+i);k++) // Aceita preencher com os novos valores do vetor aumentado dinamicamente
      {
          printf ("\nDigite o %d numero do vetor: ",k+1);
          fflush(stdin);
          scanf ("%d",&p[k]);
      }
      printf ("\n\n\t\t========== VETOR PREENCHIDO REALOCADO ==========\n");
      for (k=0;k<(n+i);k++) // Mostra vetor REalocado
      {
           printf ("\t\t%d",p[k]);
      }
      free(p); // Libera o espaço de memoria que utilizamos
      return 0;
      system("pause");
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu dei uma melhorada na legibilidade do código e dei uma modernizada, mas o erro mesmo está na hora de pegar as posições do novo *array*. Está começando na posição 0 que já foi preenchida, tem que começar de onde parou no antigo, já que o novo tem 5 posições tem que preencher as 4 e 5 e não 0 e 1 como está ocorrendo. Olha o `i` no lugar do 0. Muitas vezes é difícil perceber isto pela falta de legibilidade.

```
for (int k = i; k < (n + i); k++) {
```

Veja:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int i;
    printf("\nDigite a quantidade de numeros que serao digitados: ");
    scanf ("%d", &i);
    int *p = malloc(i * sizeof(int));
    if (p == NULL) {
        printf ("\nERRO.MEMORIA INSUFICIENTE");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
        printf ("\nDigite o % do valor do vetor: ", k + 1);
        scanf ("%d", &p[k]);
    }
    printf("\n\n========== VETOR PREENCHIDO ==========\n");
    for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) printf ("%d\t", p[k]);
    printf("\n\nSeu vetor possui %d elementos.", i);
    printf("\nDigite um valor positivo para aumentar ao vetor.");
    printf("\nDigite um valor negativo para diminuir do vetor.\n\n");
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if (!(i + n)) {
        printf("\nSeu vetor possui 0 elementos.\n\n");
        exit(1);
    } else if ((i + n) < 0) {
        printf("\nSeu vetor possui quantidade negativa de elemento.\n\nIMPOSSIVEL ALOCAR MEMORIA.\n\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    p = realloc(p, (i + n) * sizeof(int));
    if (p == NULL) {
        printf("\nERRO DE RE-ALOCACAO.MEMORIA INSUFICIENTE");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (int k = i; k < (n + i); k++) { //<==================== o erro estava aqui
        printf("\nDigite o % do valor do vetor: ",k+1);
        scanf("%d", &p[k]);
    }
    printf("\n\n========== VETOR PREENCHIDO REALOCADO ==========\n");
    for (int k = 0; k < (n+i); k++) {
        printf("%d\t", p[k]);
    }
    free(p); //na prática não é necessário aqui porque o programa vai encerrar, mas pra fins de aprendizado ok
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/9NyDbt). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/soykkwwy-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/ContinuousArray.c).

Comment: Troque de compilador, esse seu é muito antigo e vai te ensinar fazer tudo errado, ou veja se tem que configurá-lo para usar C99.

Comment: Desculpe, apaguei sem querer o comentário, queria edita-lo. É que sou iniciante ainda, como altero para C99? (não sei o que é isso)

Comment: CONSEGUI AMIGO, Estou utilizando o CodeBlocks, consegui ativar o C99, fui em Settings>Compiler>e marquei a opcao -std=c99... mas o que é isso? heheheheh

Comment: Você estava usando uma configuração de um C muito antigo, o 99 é o ano da padronização. O CodeBlocks não é um compilador, é só um IDE. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101

Comment: @weise: C99 é [isto aqui](http://www.dii.uchile.cl/~daespino/files/Iso_C_1999_definition.pdf). Tem também [C89/C90](http://read.pudn.com/downloads133/doc/565041/ANSI_ISO%2B9899-1990%2B[1].pdf) e [C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).