# SharpDevelop X Visual Studio: são equivalentes em tudo?

Tags: visual-studio, ide

O SharpDevelop é equivalente ao VS ou não, falta muito para chegar lá. Eu vejo grandes dificuldades em instalar certos pacotes, por exemplo, o `Microsoft.ServiceBus.Notifications`. É uma alternativa para pequenos projetos?

Comment: O visual studio é mais complexo, o SharpDevelop e menos complexo, mais leve e mais rápido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não, nem teria como ser, são produtos completamente diferentes. Basicamente ambos desejam atender a mesma necessidade, mas cada um vai por seu caminho, fora o que é padrão da linguagem, eles são completamente incompatíveis, exceto por coincidência.

Daí a usar algum pacote existente para o código não deve mudar nada. [IDE é uma coisa, linguagem é outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101) e a última é igual em qualquer lugar. Se algo foi feito para rodar com alguma implementação do .NET vai rodar igual em todos lugares que use para desenvolver. O que pode ocorrer é ter algum problema com a plataforma, algo que uma implementação não permite, mas se a implementação é o .NET Framework será igual no Visual Studio ou no #Develop.

Se está com alguma dificuldade específica deve perguntar especificamente por isso.

Comment: Não, não estou. Só queria saber mesmo a diferença, até para um dia quem sabe, poder fazer a escolha precisa. Sei que a pergunta é ampla, mas a resposta do big deu para entender os dois ambientes.