# Como colocar legendas embaixo no Chart?

Tags: c#, gráfico, chart

Tenho tentado trabalhar com o Chart em C#.

Mas agora não consigo deixar todos as legendas de baixo de suas respectivas colunas.

A imagem mostra que a legenda 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 e 11 não estão aparecendo, mesmo que elas estejam nomeadas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe como configurar para todas a legendas da coluna aparecer?

Comment: O projeto é Windows Forms? Por favor, não use a tag `visual-studio` para problemas que não são relacionados com a IDE. Se tiver dúvidas sobre o que é e o que não é IDE, indico a [leitura desta publicação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/18246).

Comment: Talvez essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7568047/6000539) te ajude;

Comment: @MárcioCristian Resolveu, Ofereça como resposta penso que vai ajudar mais pessoas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566996/force-all-axis-labels-to-show/7568047#7568047), é só setar o `Interval = 1`, pois forçará a exibição dos Labels independentemente dos tamanhos.

Ex:

```
ChartID.Areas("myChartAreaName").AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval = 1
```