# Como usar o conio.h no netbeans

Tags: c, netbeans

estou a fazer um protejo em c do jogo torre de hanoi.
Precisava de utilizar a biblioteca  mas não estou a conseguir,sempre que tento adicionar da-me erro. 
se alguém me conseguir ajudar.

Comment: Simples, não use. Primeiro que o NetBeans é só um IDE. Segundo que isto é considerado obsoleto. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101

Comment: Está a utilizar `<conio.h>` só para o `getch()` ?

Comment: nao estou a usar para poder usar SetConsoleCursorPosition