# StackOverflowException em c# pelo visual studio code Linux

Tags: c#, exceção, visual-studio-code

Estou tentando aprender um pouco de c#, e o site da microsoft me incentiva a utilizar o vscode para programar no linux, porém estou tendo um problema de StackOverflowException e não consigo entender o motivo (o código não roda nenhum loop visualmente infinito).

Segue o código principal:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
        UserInfo info = new UserInfo("user","password");
        Console.WriteLine(info.user);
}
```

E o código da classe UserInfo

```
public class UserInfo {
    public string user {
        get {
            return this.user;
        }

        set {
            this.user = user;
        }
    }

    public string password {
        get {
            return this.cryptPassword(this.password);
        }

        set {
            this.password = password;
        }
    }

    public UserInfo(string user, string password) {
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;
    }

    private string cryptPassword(string password){
        string[] cryptArray = password.Split("");
        string[] reverseArray = new string[cryptArray.Length];

        for(int index = 0; index < cryptArray.Length; index++){
            reverseArray[index] = cryptArray[cryptArray.Length - index];
        } 

        string crypt = string.Join("",cryptArray);

        return $"HASH{crypt}000";
    }
}
```

E todos os arquivos estão dentro do mesmo namespace.

Então o que eu estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu problema esta aqui:

```
public string user {
    get {
        return this.user;
    }

    set {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

Voce esta se referenciando ao nome propriedade e não ao nome da variável privada, o que resulta em um loop infinito na hora do get.

Você deve criar a variável privada para password e user assim (retirei o método cryptPassword só pra simplificar a explicação):

```
public static void Main()
{
    UserInfo info = new UserInfo("user","password");
    Console.WriteLine(info.User);
    Console.WriteLine(info.Password);
}

public class UserInfo {

private string _user;
private string _password;   

public string User {
    get {
        return _user;
    }

    set {
        _user = value;
    }
}

public string Password {
    get {
        return _password;
    }

    set {
        _password = value;
    }
}

public UserInfo(string user, string password) {
    this.User = user;
    this.Password = password;
}
```

Comment: functionou aqui, obrigado. Essa semântica do get e set me lembrou muito do Kotlin / scala, ficarei mais atento a isso agora :)

Answer (score 4):

Perceba que todas as suas propriedades o seu acessor SET chama recursivamente ele mesmo, ai que esta o seu problema. Se você quer encapsular dessa forma, você precisa de um field private para segurar esses valores.

```
private string user;
public string User {
    get {
        return this.user;
    }
    set {
        this.user = value;
    }
}
```

Se estiver na versão acima do C# 3.0, você pode utilizar o auto-property:

```
public string User { get; set; } //Obedecendo o Pascal Case
```

Em tempo de compilação vai ser feito um field privado para fazer esse encapsulamento assim como os seus métodos acessores, seria feito algo como o Java trabalha com métodos Get e Set:

```
public string get_User {...}
public void set_User (string value) {...}
```

Comment: Para um `getter` não padrão, como o do `password`, eu posso continuar declarando o `setter` de maneira implícita é só declarar a implementação do `getter`?

Comment: Infelizmente você não consegue implementar um sem implementar o outro também. Logo o auto-property não vai funcionar e você precisa especificar um field privado igual eu fiz no primeiro exemplo.

Comment: obrigado pela resposta :), eu havia olhado esse auto-property mas acho que olhei bem por cima,  me lembra muito os accessors do ruby