# Armazenar valores em matrizes

Tags: c, matriz

Estou usando o codeblocks, sou iniciante na programação, iniciando com C, por conta da faculdade.

O erro é esse: No trecho do código onde ele armazena o valor da média do aluno, só armazena o valor correto da média do primeiro aluno, os médias dos alunos seguintes o algoritmo não faz média corretamente, ou seja, inicialmente ele calcula a média, a partir do segundo aluno ele não armazena o valor correto.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct aluno{
    char nome[50];
    float nota[6];
    float media;
};

main()
{
    int i, j;
    float soma, troca;
    char classificado[10];
    soma = 0;

    struct aluno ficha[6];
    // Entrada de dados
    for (i=1; i<6; i++){
    printf("\n Digite o nome do aluno: ");
    scanf("%s", &ficha[i].nome);
    printf("\n Nome: %s", ficha[i].nome);
        for (j=1; j<5; j++){
            printf("\n Informe a nota: ",j);
            scanf("%f", &ficha[i].nota[j]);
            soma =  soma + ficha[i].nota[j];
        }
        ficha[i].media = soma/4;
        printf("\n A média do  aluno é: %f",ficha[i].media);


    }
    // Reordernação de vetor para crescente
     for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        for(j=i+1; j<6; j++){
            if(ficha[i].media > ficha[j].media){
                troca = ficha[i].media;
                ficha[i].media = ficha[j].media;
                ficha[i].media = ficha[j].media;
                ficha[j].media = troca;

            }// if
        }
    }




    for(i=1; i<6; i++){
    printf("\n Os nomes dos alunos são: %s",ficha[i].nome);
    }
    // Saída de dados
    for(i=1; i<6; i++){
    printf("\n A média do  aluno é: %2f",ficha[i].media);
    }



}
```

Depois de compilado

[image: Depois de compilado]

Comment: `soma = 0` tem de estar dentro do primeiro `for`, senão não limpa a soma entre alunos.

Comment: Code::Blocks não é um compilador, veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101

Comment: Muito obrigado Ricardo, resolveu mesmo. Obrigado também Maniero. 

Apesar de ter resolvido, poderia me dizer Ricardo, qual  a razão de ter que colocar dentro do primeiro for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Codeblocks é um ambiente de desenvolvimento, na qual tem compatibilidade para vários compiladores.

Avaliando o seu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct aluno{
    char nome[50];
    float nota[6];
    float media;
};

main()
{
    int i, j;
    float soma, troca;
    char classificado[10];
    soma = 0;

    struct aluno ficha[6];
    // Entrada de dados
    for (i=1; i<6; i++){
    printf("\n Digite o nome do aluno: ");
    scanf("%s", &ficha[i].nome);
    printf("\n Nome: %s", ficha[i].nome);
        for (j=1; j<5; j++){
            printf("\n Informe a nota: ",j);
            scanf("%f", &ficha[i].nota[j]);
            soma =  soma + ficha[i].nota[j];
        }
        ficha[i].media = soma/4;
        printf("\n A média do  aluno é: %f",ficha[i].media);


    }
    // Reordernação de vetor para crescente
     for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        for(j=i+1; j<6; j++){
            if(ficha[i].media > ficha[j].media){
                troca = ficha[i].media;
                ficha[i].media = ficha[j].media;
                ficha[i].media = ficha[j].media;
                ficha[j].media = troca;

            }// if
        }
    }




    for(i=1; i<6; i++){
    printf("\n Os nomes dos alunos são: %s",ficha[i].nome);
    }
    // Saída de dados
    for(i=1; i<6; i++){
    printf("\n A média do  aluno é: %2f",ficha[i].media);
    }



}
```

Percebi que a `soma=0` poderia ser dentro do primeiro for para zerar a nota a cada novo aluno;

Vi também que os dois últimos laços de repetições podem virar um só, por exemplo:

```
for(i=1; i<6; i++){
    printf("\n Os nomes dos alunos são: %s",ficha[i].nome);
    printf("\n A média do  aluno é: %2f",ficha[i].media);
    }
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado Yoda, bem observado !

Comment: @FelipeMascarenhas se consegui lhe ajudar pode aceitar a resposta :D , como diz nesse post https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 1):

é só zerar a soma no final do segundo loop for:

```
for (i=1; i<6; i++){
printf("\n Digite o nome do aluno: ");
scanf("%s", &ficha[i].nome);
printf("\n Nome: %s", ficha[i].nome);
    for (j=1; j<5; j++){
        printf("\n Informe a nota: ",j);
        scanf("%f", &ficha[i].nota[j]);
        soma =  soma + ficha[i].nota[j];
    }
    ficha[i].media = soma/4;
    printf("\n A média do  aluno é: %f",ficha[i].media);

    soma = 0; //ADICIONAR ESSE TRECHO

}
```

Segue o código rodadndo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Percebi que a atribuição está for do `loop`, isso permite que a variável SOMA fique com o saldo da soma anterior. Para resolver o problema, coloque a atribuição do valor zero dentro do `loop`, conforme abaixo:

Você poderia otimizar seu código, verifique sua lógica e tente melhorar a saída de dados, pois não há necessidade de possuir dois loops.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct aluno{
    char nome[50];
    float nota[6];
    float media;
};

main()
{
    int i, j;
    float soma, troca;
    char classificado[10];

    struct aluno ficha[6];
    // Entrada de dados
    for (i=1; i<6; i++){
        soma:=0;
        printf("\n Digite o nome do aluno: ");
        scanf("%s", &ficha[i].nome);
        printf("\n Nome: %s", ficha[i].nome);
        for (j=1; j<5; j++){
            printf("\n Informe a nota: ",j);
            scanf("%f", &ficha[i].nota[j]);
            soma =  soma + ficha[i].nota[j];
        }
        ficha[i].media = soma/4;
        printf("\n A média do  aluno é: %f",ficha[i].media);


    }
    // Reordernação de vetor para crescente
     for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        for(j=i+1; j<6; j++){
            if(ficha[i].media > ficha[j].media){
                troca = ficha[i].media;
                ficha[i].media = ficha[j].media;
                ficha[i].media = ficha[j].media;
                ficha[j].media = troca;

            }// if
        }
    }



    // Saída de dados

    for(i=1; i<6; i++){
        printf("\n Os nomes dos alunos são: %s",ficha[i].nome);
        printf("\n A média do  aluno é: %2f",ficha[i].media);
    }

}
```