# Quantas classes podemos ter em um mesmo pacote?

Tags: java, classes, eclipse

[image: Treeview com as classes do pacote no Eclipe]

Quantas classes podemos ter num mesmo pacote?

Comment: Até onde sei não há limite, não um que seja imposto pela linguagem/IDE

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

Quantas você quiser. Mesmo que tenha um limite teórico ele é muito maior que o prático.

O que existe é só uma recomendação para uma classe por arquivo de fonte.

E isto nada tem a ver com o Eclipse, não importa se está usando este IDE ou não. É uma questão da implementação do Java que está usando. Veja [O que é linguagem de programação, IDE e compilador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101).