# Bibliotecas standards em C/C++

Tags: c, c++, biblioteca

Qual a desvantagem de utilizar bibliotecas não *standards* como por exemplo a função `getch()` e a biblioteca `conio.h`, qual a desvantagem tem do ponto de vista de desenvolvimento utilizando esse tipo de bibliotecas? Falando mais precisamente no caso de programar em C em micro processadores, web ou até software.

Tenho uma má pratica de utilizar bibliotecas não *standards* e não sei que implicações causa no meu código.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma importante é que não poderá usar em outros compiladores e plataformas já que poucos implementam isso. Uma das coisas que as pessoas não entendem que a linguagem é algo muito mais que o compilador que elas instalaram na máquina delas, que o fato de funcionar na máquina dela não quer dizer que funcionará em qualquer lugar.

Claro, ela pode até usar se tiver certeza que aquele código não será usado em outra situação, ou seja, sabendo o que está fazendo tudo pode ser feito. O problema é que a pessoa usa sem saber, aprende errado e se acostuma com isso. Embora eu não deveria me preocupar muito porque é comum que as pessoas que fazem isso não vão continuar programando em C ou C++, ela está exercitando um pouco por obrigação ou gosto, mas quando ela começar ter um monte de dificuldades ela vai desistir da linguagem e ir em algo mais fácil, os que não desistirão geralmente são os que conseguem entender todos os conceitos do que estão fazendo e procuram uma forma estrutura de aprender.

Então tem gente que diz programar em C quando ela programa em Borland C que é um dialeto da linguagem C. Só as que se conformam 100% com o padrão são C puro.

E isso costuma ser um problema maior porque geralmente está disponível em compiladores legados ou que só mantém aquilo por compatibilidade, e é comum que essas bibliotecas tenham problemas de segurança, seja pela implementação específica, seja até pelo conceito (tem várias funções padrões de C que não deveria ser usadas por esse motivo).

Essa questão de boa ou má prática tem a ver com essa coisa de não saber o porquê das coisas, tudo pode usar se souber porque está fazendo, e fazer algo que dá certo, mas não sabe o porquê, não deveria fazer. Além dos motivos gerais, cada biblioteca tem algum motivo específico para não ser usado.

Em geral usar bibliotecas C quando se programa em C++ não é muito adequado e pode trazer algumas dificuldades. Alias, esta é outra das coisas ruins que as pessoas acreditam por conhecer tudo superficialmente, C++ é uma linguagem completamente diferente de C, mas as pessoas acham que não porque ela consegue compilar quase qualquer código C.

A última frase do primeiro parágrafo não parece fazer muito sentido.

[O que é linguagem de programação, IDE e compilador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101).

Comment: Desde mais quero agradecer pela sua resposta, o que queria dizer é que estou a estudar Eng.Eletrotecnica, mais na area de micro processadores e gostava de saber a influencia que tem em nao utilizar bibliotecas padrões, porque se compilarmos irá criar um ficheiro .exe, em que qualquer pc possa executar.

Comment: Todo computador tem microprocessador, você falou em software, e tudo o que se faz em uma linguagem de programação é software, e falou web, se for *backend* não importa, se for *frontend* não estará usando C ou C++. PC não é o único tipo de computador que existe, e falando em eletrônica talvez esteja querendo falar de microcontrolador, que está longe de ser PC. E geralmente esses dispositivos usam C fora do padrão, programar para eles costuma ser muito diferente de programar para PC.

Comment: Então num microcontrolador já se pode usar todo o tipo de bibliotecas? Ou é uma forma de programar bastante diferente em que não é necessário importar esse tipo de bibliotecas? Ainda não comecei a estudar essa parte dos microcontroladores e então não sei o que me espera em termos de programação a esse respeito.

Comment: Não, exatamente o oposto, só se pode usar as bibliotecas que existem para ele, que muitas vezes nem são as padrões, o compilador usado em microcontroladores frequentemente não são de C padrão, é u dialeto dele. Não chega ser totalmente diferente, mas tem diferenças fundamentais. E tem exceções onde usa-se o padrão. Mas ainda o jeito de programar pode ser diferente por questões da limitação daquele hardware ou pelo requisito de exceção, muitas vezes precisa ser um *hard real time*.

Comment: Para terminar, se tiver algumas artigos que recomende a ler sobre este assunto agradeço bastante. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Nada específico.