# Problemas wprintf com long int c++

Tags: c++

Olá, estou tendo problemas ao tentar dar "print" em inteiros "grandes" no c++.

Pra ser mais específico, utilizando o visual studio 2017

```
int main() {
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    long rr = 6448915477954560;
    wprintf(L"%ld\n", rr);
}
```

Problema: o valor mostrado no console, difere do digitado, imprimindo: 608174080

Comment: E porque usar o `wprintf()`? Por que não usar o bom e velho `cout`?

Comment: por questões de estética no console, estou usando o "_setmode" para permitir o uso de caracteres tipo: "çñãê..." no console, isso me obriga a usar wprintf. Porém, ao remover o _setmode e voltar a usar o cout normalmente, o problema continua (isso só acontece no vs2017)

Comment: é estranho pq o VS2017 é só um IDE. E eu uso tudo direitinho com `cout`, portanto o problema é outro. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101

Answer (score 1):

Tu estás provavelmente [estourando o long com esse número](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types). Tenta:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>  
#include <io.h>  
#include <wchar.h>



int main() {
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    long long rr = 6448915477954560;
    wprintf(L"%lld\n", rr);
}
```

[Compilador online com o código](http://rextester.com/l/c_online_compiler_visual)