# Por que o IDE indica que um código no "if" não será executado?

Tags: java, if, condição

Observe o código:

[image: Código no IDE]

Porque a IDE de desenvolvimento não está considerando o código da linha 34, 35 e 36?

Não era para ter entrado dentro da condicional?

Comment: 5 nunca é maior que 6. A condição nunca será verdadeira. Por isso não deve entrar nunca dentro da condicional.

Comment: Seu código tem outras coisas estranhas. Por exemplo, na linha 39 você está fazendo um assignment que sempre vai retornar true, dentro da condição do `if`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IDEs apenas mostram isso pra você, provavelmente ele [não é o que está pensando](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101). O compilador é que entende o código e gera algo que será executado ou não. Nesse caso não há nada de errado com o código. O que IDEs fazem é orientar quando vê algo que é esquisito e não deveria estar ali. É o caso dessas três linhas que não precisam existir. Como 5 nunca é maior que 6 a condição sempre será falsa e o conteúdo do `if` nunca será executado, então todas as três linhas são inócuas e deveriam ser retiradas do código. Mesmo que fosse sempre verdadeiro aí o `if` poderia ser eliminado, deixando só o incremento direto sem condicional.

Por consequência neste caso nunca entrará no condicional quando for executado, é uma clara condição falsa e o IDE já informou isso para você não perder tempo com esse código

Comment: muito obrigado mesmo.