# Problema pós-incremento

Tags: php, operadores, echo

Problema no pós-incremento retornando 67 sendo que era pra retornar 7:

```
<?php 

$a = 10;
$b = 6;


echo ++$a; // pré incremento

echo "<br>";

echo $b++;

"<br>";

echo$b; // pós incremento

echo"<br>";



echo--$a;// pré decremento

 ?>
```

Comment: Sai 67 somente porque os dois valores aparecem juntos. Veja que você não colocou o `echo` no `"<br>"` entre os valores, o que fez o PHP simplesmente ignorar a *string*. Veja em https://repl.it/@acwoss/CookedNaturalTelephones.

Comment: Pela *tag* usada anteriormente deve ler isto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 3):

Provavelmente vo9cê só esqueceu de colocar um `echo`. Assim deve fazer o que deseja:

```
$a = 10;
$b = 6;
echo ++$a; // pre incremento
echo "<br>";
echo $b++;
echo "<br>";
echo$b; // pós incremento
echo"<br>";
echo--$a;// pré decremento
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/NV3IyZ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/aadfvjzf-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Engine/Echo.php).

No seu código mandava imprimir 6 depois tinha um `"<br>"` solto que desaparece no resultado e depois manda imprimir o 7, como não tem nada separando-os fica 67.

Comment: foi isso mesmo muito obrigado

Comment: @GabrielFlor veja no [tour] a melhor forma de dizer obrigado.