# Pegar sempre os três últimos caracteres sem saber o tamanho da String

Tags: java, string, substring

Eu quero pegar os três últimos caracteres de uma `String`. Exemplo:

```
String x = "OlaMundo"
```

Saída:

> ```
> ndo
> ```

Eu até consigo fazer isso usando `substring`, o problema é que eu não sei o tamanho da `String`, eu não sei qual é a palavra.

Existe alguma forma de fazer isso sem saber o tamanho específico da `String`?

Comment: O tamanho da String é sempre determinável através do método `length()`

Comment: Pela *tag* usada anteriormente deve ler isto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101. A sua pergunta é sobre Java e não tinha a *tag*. Não era sobre o Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você não quiser se preocupar fazendo validação de tamanho da string, pode usar a classe `StringUtils` do pacote `import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;` ([link da biblioteca](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#right(java.lang.String,%20int))), ficaria assim:

```
String x = StringUtils.right("MinhaString", 3);
```

Answer (score 2):

A forma mais básica seria pegando o tamanho:

```
x.substring(x.length() - 3);
```

O único problema é se a *string* for menor que 3, aí teria que verificar antes. Se for usar assim é mais simples que usar uma biblioteca. Se quiser fazer o tratamento aconselho criar uma função, assim:

```
class Program {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Right("OlaMundo", 3));
    }

    public static String Right(String text, int length) {
        if (text.length() <= length) return null;
        return text.substring(text.length() - length);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/6MxHpL). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/smahiiig-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/String/Right.java).

Comment: com isso é possível eu fazer uma comparação com uma outra String? saída = and?

Comment: @LuccasBarrosTavares Comparação de `Strings` em Java é sempre como o método `equals` e não `==`

Comment: opa, acho que respondi na pressa rsrs, mas eae? como eu faria a comparação? to tentando comparar, mas sem sucesso

Answer (score 0):

Você pode pegar o tamanho dela usando

```
suaString.substring(suaString.length() - 3);
```

Você só terá problemas se sua String tiver menos que três caracteres

Como o método `.length()` retorna um número (tipo inteiro), você pode fazer algo do tipo para pode comparar antes de usar:

```
if (suaString.length() >= 3) {
//Implanta o código
} else {
System.out.println("Sua String é menor que três caracteres!")
}
```