# C++ - É correto criar novos tipos utilizando using?

Tags: c++

Certa vez em algum post aqui no sopt vi que criar novos tipos em C++ com `typedef` deveria ser uma prática a ser abandonada pois isso é uma prática de C, e em C++ o correto seria utilizar `using nomedotipo = tipo;`, então utilizando esta nova maneira pude ver que o visual studio apesar de criar um novo tipo, ele também criava um outro chamado de estrutura não nomeada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não entendi o que deseja saber e o que esta tela tem a ver com a questão. Parte do problema talvez seja porque confunde as funções das coisas, veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101 Ou pode ser só que a pergunta esteja incompleta e não dizendo o que é importante para entender a dúvida.

Comment: @Maniero eu queria saber se criar novos tipos com using é correto ou é só uma "gambiarra", o que me fez fazer a pergunta foi o vstudio ter indicado que o novo tipo também é uma estrutura sem nome, como se fosse um problema como indicado na imagem

Comment: Se você leu aqui alguém dizendo que é correto, porque está desconfiado? A resposta estava negativada? Existe algo mais além de só querer a confirmação se aquilo é verdade? Onde isto que você está dizendo está indicado? Normalmente o `using` não é para usar assim, deve ter um motivo, eu disse normalmente, este parece um caso para só declarar a `struct` de forma normal, sem `using` e sem `typedef`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `using` pode ser parametrizado, o `typedef` não. Exceto por isso são idênticos.

Não sei porque o Visual Studio se complica com isso. O Qt Creator também mostra de maneira estranha. Não tentei outros IDEs.