# Problema de reconhecimento de classe no Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, sintaxe

Há um problema no meu projeto que supostamente a ser a classe principal .

[image: esse problema]

Comment: o erro esta nessa parte `string args[]` args nao 'e um vetor, voce pode mudar para `string[] args` ou somente `string args`

Answer (score 1):

Lamento estar há uma semana com problemas por um erro de digitação, inclusive a mensagem de erro mostra claramente que o método escreve em minúsculo `main()`. Não garanto que seja o único problema no código, mas este é fácil de resolver, inclusive tem coisas muito sofisticadas no código, e são coisas que apenas programadores bem avançados deveriam mexer.

Como tem erro de digitação no texto da pergunta também minha sugestão é sempre ficar atento a isto, pode ser que ocorra várias vezes.

Note que o Eclipse é só o emissor da mensagem, ele nada tem a ver com seu problema, este é um problema no seu código que está sendo compilado pelo Java, então este é o assunto do seu probelma e não o IDE. Sugiro ler [O que é linguagem de programação, IDE e compilador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101) para entender melhor o papel de cada coisa.

Comment: muito obrigada vou seguir seu conselho

Comment: @nikolasBinottiAlves veja a melhor forma de dizer obrigado no [tour].