# Sobrescrita do Equals() e HashCode()

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

Estou aprendendo a utilizar o `equals()` e `hashCode()`, e fui ensinado que o Eclipse sobrescreve esse método para nós. Porém estou tentando comprar dois atributos para falar se um objeto é igual ao outro.

Exemplificando melhor: Se um produto tem o mesmo código, porém seu tamanho é diferente, eles devem ser considerados objetos diferentes. Estou utilizando `HashMap` para essa implementação.

O `Equals()` e `HashCode()` estão assim:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = super.hashCode();
    result = prime * result + ((super.getCodigo() == null) ? 0 : super.getCodigo().hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((getTamanho() == null) ? 0 : getTamanho().hashCode());
    return result;
}


@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (!super.equals(obj))
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    ProdutoComTamanho other = (ProdutoComTamanho) obj;
    if (super.getCodigo() == null) {
        if (other.getCodigo() != null)
            return false;
    } else
        return false;
    if (getTamanho() == null) {
        if (other.getTamanho() != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!getTamanho().equals(other.getTamanho()) && !super.getCodigo().equals(other.getCodigo()))
        return false;
    return true; 
}
```

Quando testo a aplicação ele não os considera como objetos diferentes, somente quando eu altero o código do produto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Eclipse apenas gera um código para você, nada mais que isto, quem sobrescreve é o compilador. Leia mais em [O que é linguagem de programação, IDE e compilador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101).

[O que você chama de atributo na verdade chama campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

Não entendi sobre o que deseja com o `hashCode()`. Quase ninguém fala sobre isto, mas chega ser uma sacanagem ter um `hashCode()` em `Object`. Quase sempre ter esse método em classes mutáveis, pelo menos nos campos que fazem parte do cálculo código *hash*, é um erro. Este código deveria ser estável. Se você usar um código instável em um `HashMap` ou algo semelhante terá problemas, você o adiciona de um jeito e vai buscar de outro, não acha.

Se a conversão de `obj` para o tipo `ProdutoComTamanho` falhar seu código irá quebrar, tem que testar se deu certo.

Tem algumas coisas esquisitas no código e sem dizer porque está fazendo pode estar certo ou errado, não temos como saber. Essa herança por exemplo parece ruim, mas há caso que pode ser adequada.

O operador relacional está errado, basta uma das duas comparações serem diferentes e ele já será diferente, então o correto é usar `||` e não `&&`. O operador de *or* exige apenas um para considerar verdadeiro e nem olha o outro se o primeiro dever verdadeiro, e como usa uma negação na primeira expressão ele é verdadeira se i código for diferente, ele já deveria entrar no `if`.

Answer (score 1):

Eu fiz os testes com uma classe criada com código, nome e tamanho. Gerei automaticamente pelo eclipse e funcionou perfeitamente.

No seu código, em algumas situações aparece super.getCodigo(), estou deduzindo que a classe ProdutoComTamanho herda da classe Produto... da uma olhada nas duas classes, como é um projeto acadêmico o erro pode está no getCodigo da super classe.