# Código executa uma linha que deveria ser condicional

Tags: c, c++, if, else

Estou fazendo um trabalho para faculdade em C++ e, ao realizar um if/else para um valor de `totalf` igual ou diferente de 0, ele não é obedecido. Como faço para que a saída **exiba apenas** um determinado `printf` da **condição correta**?

Segue a saída:

[image: Resultado]

Segue o código:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main() {

       int filial;
       float v1, v2, v3, totalf;

       printf("\ndigite o numero da filial: ");
       scanf("%d", &filial);

       printf("Digite o valor do 1 mes de vendas: ");
       scanf("%f", &v1);

       printf("Digite o valor do 2 mes de vendas: ");
       scanf("%f", &v2);

       printf("Digite o valor do 3 mes de vendas: ");
       scanf("%f", &v3);

       totalf = v1 + v2 + v3;

           if(totalf != 0)
       printf("\no valor total desta filial sera de: %f", totalf);
           else(total == 0);
       printf("\nO valor nao podera ser exibido, favor digitar um valor diferente de 0");

       return 0;

    }
```

<sup>[Imagem do código e output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGEB3.png)</sup>

Comment: Sugiro que leia as diretrizes da comunidade para fazer uma [boa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Vou recomendar o abandono de Dev-C++. Essa IDE não é atualizada há muitos anos e contém inúmeros problemas. Existem alternativas melhores. No momento, vou recomendar o [Visual Studio Community Edition](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/features/cplusplus/) por ter um bom suporte e inúmeros tutoriais de uso da IDE. Também funciona em Linux.

Comment: @José, sugiro ao Douglas que utilize também o [Code::Blocks IDEs](http://www.codeblocks.org/).

Comment: Creio que a pergunta não deveria ser editada para correção do código postado pelo autor. Da maneira como ficou algumas respostas ficaram totalmente sem sentido. Se quiser corrigir o código faça em sua resposta.

Comment: @THIAGODEBONIS Recomendo que ele use uma IDE como Atom ou Sublime Text. Para a compilção usar um compilador como o GCC ou MinGW (se for Windows).

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 4):

Havia um `;` onde não devia finalizando o `else`, então esta cláusula do `if` fazia nada e a linha seguinte executava incondicionalmente. Este é o erro principal que faz o ocorrido

Além disto há uma condição no `else`, isto não é necessário neste caso e na forma realizada nem pode ser assim, ou deixa sem condição ou faz um `else if` (quando couber, não neste caso). Por isso minha recomendação é sempre que usar `if` ou `else` de uma linha, coloque sempre na mesma linha do condicional como eu fiz no código abaixo. Ou então use chaves sempre. Não iria resolver esse problema e nem ele seria evitado, mas fica um visual mais fácil.

Mas também tem um problema que é mais difícil perceber que é o tipo de dado usado. Um tipo `float` não tem exatidão e não deveria ser usado para comparação que exija isto como está fazendo. Ou seja, não deveria ser usado nunca como valor monetário. Especialmente a igualdade ou diferença pode dar falsos negativos por causa da falta de exatidão.

Eu minimizei o problema verificando se é maior, mas ainda pode dar alguma situação de erro, improvável, mas pode. O certo mesmo é não usar este tip ode dado. Veja mais em [Qual a forma correta de usar os tipos float, double e decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101).

Neste caso o problema não é o `if` e sim o tipo de dados. E o `if` não é uma função, por isso não tem parâmetros, acho importante deixar claro essas coisas.

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main() {
    int filial;
    float v1, v2, v3;
    printf("\ndigite o numero da filial: ");
    scanf("%d", &filial);
    printf("Digite o valor do 1 mes de vendas: ");
    scanf("%f", &v1);
    printf("Digite o valor do 2 mes de vendas: ");
    scanf("%f", &v2);
    printf("Digite o valor do 3 mes de vendas: ");
    scanf("%f", &v3);
    float totalf = v1 + v2 + v3;
    if (totalf > 0) printf("\no valor total desta filial sera de: %f", totalf);
    else printf("\nO valor nao podera ser exibido, favor digitar um valor diferente de 0");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ipEONL). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/FloatCompare). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Typing/FloatCompare.c).

Como já falaram deveria evitar o DevC++, ainda que [seu problema nada tem a ver com ele](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101), e deveria programar C++ em C++, está usando código C em C++. Escolha qual dos dois vai programar, são linguagens diferentes, apesar de C++ entender código C.

Comment: E ai meu mestre! O que você acha da minha resposta ao mesmo, será que entrei com muitos detalhes? Eu me baseio nos seus tipos de respostas para criar as minhas, pois sou novo na comunidade.

Comment: Não sou dono da verdade, mas vejo alguns problemas na sua resposta. Muito negrito, acaba perdendo o sentido quando tem tantos, mas nada grave. Gosto de respostas detalhes, mas acho que falou muito de algo tem importância próxima de zero para a pergunta, nem mesno para entender o contexto do erro, apesar de ser um conteúdo bom. Aí começa o que achei um pouco pior e tem mais importância: Não precisa inicializar as variáveis neste caso porque todas variáveis serão preenchidas com entradas ou calculadas no primeiro momento, se olhar meu código ficar até mais evidente. Não está errado fazer, mas...

Comment: ...não precisa e é uma recomendação que beira o equívoco. E não resolve o problema, então nesse ponto a resposta não é boa.

Comment: @Maniero tinha um outro erro que tiraram da pergunta ao transcrever o código: `else(total == 0)`. Recoloquei ele lá pois faz parte do problema. Precisa de uma edição na sua resposta citando isso para fechar com chave de ouro já que provavelmente viu a versão sem o erro.

Comment: @José obrigado, acabei de editar falando nisso.

Comment: @Maniero de acordo com o seu feedback atualizei a minha resposta também.

Comment: @THIAGODEBONIS claro que melhorou, mas não muito porque em essência só mexeu na formatação que era algo absolutamente secundário.

Comment: @Maniero o senhor é muito exigente :D. Eu dei uma resposta mais completa, pois ele é novato e eu tentei explicar com mais detalhes os tipos de erros principais e quais são, ao final eu editei a resposta também referente ao `else` que tinham alterado apontando o seus erros.

Comment: @THIAGODEBONIS na verdade você viu que sua edição acabou gerando confusão e escondeu o real problema?

Comment: muito obrigado ajudou bastante, realmente eu estou tendo alguns problemas com essa IDE do DEV, irei utilizar outras e a questão do float, eu não sabia que poderia ser utilizada desta forma, obrigado pela dica vou continuar me esforçando e aprender com vcs, realmente eu fico um pouco confuso e sou iniciante nesta área e vou procurar aprender mais com vcs. @Maniero

Answer (score 1):

Você não precisa colocar parâmetros no else, veja um exemplo em que faria sentido usar mais de um if e como isso seria feito:

```
if(a>5){
   printf("a é maior que 5);
} else if (a < 5){
   printf("a é menor a 5);
} else {
   printf("a é igual a 5);
}
```

Perceba que o else é a condição default caso nenhuma das condições anteriores deem certo.

Answer (score 0):

O seu `if` e está correto, porém o `else` ele não recebe nenhum parâmetro ou expressão booleana, pois ele é uma consequência do `if`, onde a tradução literal seria:

> se totalf for diferente de zero imprima XXXX, se não imprima YYYYY

**Remova a expressão boleana** do `else` e seu programa deve funcionar normalmente.

Answer (score 0):

**Existe 2 tipos de erros em programação**, os quais são:

- erros de compilação
- erros de execução

**Sobre os Erros de Compilação**

> Ocorrem quando o programa que escrevemos não obedece às regras da linguagem. Este tipo de erro são normalmente fáceis de detectar. Os mais frequentes são:

- Esquecer um ponto e vírgula
- Esquecer de fechar uma chaveta
- Esquecer de fechar as aspas num `printf` ou `scanf`
- Esquecer de fechar um comentário
- Esquecer a declaração de variáveis
- Escrever mal uma palavra (ex: `studio.h` em vez de `stdio.h`)

**Sobre os Erros de Execução**

> São mais delicados, imperceptíveis. O programa compila normalmente sem erros, mas ao ser executado não faz aquilo que estamos à espera que faça. Na gíria informática, denominamos este **tipo de erros por bugs**.
>
> Muitos principiantes em programação ficam frustrados quando não conseguem detectar os **bugs**. Com a experiência, vão ver que começam a detectá-los com rapidez. O importante é não entrarem em pânico.
>
> Para se detectar um **bug**, devem tentar isolar o erro. Isso pode ser feito utilizando `printf` no meio do código para ver o que é que o programa está a fazer passo a passo. Em alternativa, existem programas especiais denominados de **debuggers** que permitem executar o programa passo a passo e ver o conteúdo das variáveis do programa.
>
> De seguida, apresenta-se alguns **bugs** clássicos que ocorrem em `C`. São clássicos porque não existe nenhum programador de `C` que nunca os tenha feito. Tenho a certeza que mais tarde ou mais cedo todos vós também vão cometer (ou já cometeram) estes erros, os quais são:

- Esquecer de inicializar variáveis
- Esquecer o `&` (comercial) no `scanf`
- Não colocar as `flags` corretas (`%d`,`%c`,`%f`,...) no `printf` ou `scanf`
- Utilizar `=` em vez de `==`
- Ciclo infinito
- Ponto e vírgula no lugar errado
- Não agrupar instruções quando se pretende uma instrução composta

O seu código possui alguns destes problemas, então vamos analisar o mesmo agora para fazermos as correções...

**Primeiro Problema (Esqueceu de inicializar as variáveis):**

```
int filial;
float v1, v2, v3, totalf;
```

**Correção:**

```
int filial = 0;
float v1 = 0.0, v2 = 0.0, v3 = 0.0, totalf = 0.0;
```

**Segundo Problema (Não agrupar instruções quando se pretende uma instrução composta e não inserir condições lógicas no** `else`)**:**

```
  if(totalf != 0)
printf("\no valor total desta filial sera de: %f", totalf);
  else(total == 0)
printf("\nO valor nao podera ser exibido, favor digitar um valor diferente de 0");
```

**Correção (Indente corretamente o** `printf` **e remova a expressão** `(total == 0)` **do** `else`**:**

```
if(totalf != 0)
   printf("\no valor total desta filial sera de: %f", totalf);
else
   printf("\nO valor nao podera ser exibido, favor digitar um valor diferente de 0");
```

**Ou (Fechar o Bloco de Código com Chaves):**

```
 if(totalf != 0) {
    printf("\no valor total desta filial sera de: %f", totalf);
 } else {
    printf("\nO valor nao podera ser exibido, favor digitar um valor diferente de 0");
 }
```

**Ou (Utilizar Operador Condicional Ternário):**

```
(totalf != 0) ? printf("\no valor total desta filial sera de: %f", totalf) : printf("\nO valor nao podera ser exibido, favor digitar um valor diferente de 0");
```

Answer (score -2):

Para facilitar a compreensão, cada vez q você ler a palavra "else", traduza para "senão". 
Em um if simples, como desse caso, a condição !=0 já foi testada primeiro, portanto, subentende-se que a outra alternativa lógica seja a sentença ==0, então, não precisa colocá-la dentro do else.